# how can I make cron run a job right now, for testing/debugging? without changing the schedule!

Tags: cron, debugging

I have a cron job that is scheduled to run everyday, other than changing the schedule, is there any other way to do a test run of the command right now to see if it works as intended?

EDIT: (from the comments) I know the command works fine when enter it in shell (my shell), but I want to know if it works correctly when cron runs it, it could be affected by ENV or shell specific stuff (~ expansion) or ownership and permission stuff or ...

Comment: I don't understand your question? Why not simply run the command?

Comment: I know the command works when enter it in shell (my shell), but I want to know if it works when `cron` runs it, it could be affected by ENV or shell specific stuff (`~` expansion) or ownership and permission stuff or ...

Comment: So why not create new cron job run every minute with same command?

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, but I wondered if there is a way to tell cron you want a test run on job no 7 ! Surely others have had this problem/request/wish before!

Comment: Very late to the scene here through google but there was everything wrong about favadi's reply. It was clear he wanted to test it from cron and without editing the crontab specifically to do that. LIttle worse than someone telling you what you want is wrong when they have'nt tried to understand the use case.

Comment: @Ali your question is 100% valid (too bad people were originally so skeptical). Meanwhile, however, please consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @pestophagous yeah, I think there are quite a few good and helpful answers here, still seems like the correct answer to the question is the one accepted. Strictly speaking you cannot make cron itself run the command, you need to run things using some other tool, which kinda defeats the purpose. which one would you say is the correct answer?

Comment: @Ali when you put it that way, I understand your rationale (that strictly speaking there is no cron-native way to make cron itself run the task at an improvised time). The answer from Vadim-Sluzky can be useful in many cases, but for those truly-hard-to-pin-down issues, Michael-Barton's answer is more appropriate. I guess if you just "un-select" the current correct one and leave it with no "officially" correct one, then votes alone will allow other things to rise to the top.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to directly do that as cron has a special purpose - running schedules commands at a specific time. So the best thing is to either to  manually create a (temporary) crontab entry or write a script which removes and resets the environment.

Explanation of "removes and resets the environment":

A wrapper script could be started with `env -i` (which removes the environment), which would source a saved environment (making sure to export all variables, possibly by setting `set -a` first) before starting your script.

The saved environment would be the default environment of a cron job, recorded by running `env` (or `declare -p` depending on what shell your cron jobs use) as a cronjob, saving its output.

Comment: Parsing the output from ``env`` is unreliable and therefore dangerous.  Environment variable values can contain any character other than nul; you would need to handle the standard problematic characters, such as whitespace and quotes.

Answer (score 146):

You can force the crontab to run with following command:

```
run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Comment: ...on the assumption that the OP's cron job (asked 3 years ago) is in cron.daily as opposed to an individual crontab.

Comment: This does not fully simulate the cron user's environment however, so it is highly likely that you'll still have bugs because once you run your script as an actual cron job your PATH and other envvars may be different than the user you did `run-parts /etc/cron.daily` as.  I am battling this bug right now, as my script will run fine with `run-parts` but fails when actually run under the cron user.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :D.  Need to add this to my admin guide so that I don't forget it again hahah :D

Comment: how do i run cron.d/localhost which is an rsnspshot command?

Comment: It is helpful to prefix command with `sudo` on some installations like Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not run the jobs in the correct environment. Also, why would you want to run all the daily jobs just to test run a single job?

Comment: @Kusalananda You are correct about the environment. Tonight was the second time I was burned by this answer. So I posted a new [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357285/my-daily-backup-crashed-how-can-i-rerun-cron-daily/1357286#1357286) in **Ask Ubuntu**. To repeat my comment in October last year, you must prepend `sudo` to the command.

Answer (score 109):

You can simulate the cron user environment as explained in ["Running a cron job manually and immediately"](https://serverfault.com/questions/85893/running-a-cron-job-manually-and-immediately/85906). This will allow you to test the job works when it would be run as the cron user.

---

Excerpt from link:

---

**Step 1**: I put this line temporarily in the user's crontab:

```
* * * * *   /usr/bin/env > /home/username/tmp/cron-env
```

then took it out once the file was written.

**Step 2**: Made myself a little run-as-cron bash script containing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env -i $(cat /home/username/tmp/cron-env) "$@"
```

---

So then, as the user in question, I was able to

```bash
    run-as-cron /the/problematic/script --with arguments --and parameters
```

Comment: Useful trick. Of course, that won't help if you have a percent sign in your command.

Comment: Make sure to put the same shell used by the cron in the shebang line of the run-as-cron script.

Comment: Parsing (i.e., reading and interpreting) the output from ``env`` is unreliable and therefore dangerous. Environment variable values can contain any character other than nul; you should handle problematic characters, such as whitespace and quotes.

Answer (score 23):

CronitorCLI has a command `cronitor select` that lets you select and run any cron job from the command line. You do not need to create a Cronitor account to use it.

https://cronitor.io/docs/using-cronitor-cli

Here is an example:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-112:~$ cronitor select

Use the arrow keys to navigate: ↓ ↑
? Select job to run:
▸ /var/runner/src/bin/batch_reports.py runner.settings.prod
  /var/runner/src/bin/trigger_reports.py runner.settings.prod
  ... etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is really nifty!

Comment: requires some api key. 49 dollars per month.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, you can omit that step during that step (`sudo cronitor configure --api-key <API-KEY>`) during CronitorCLI installation and `cronitor select` will still work.

Comment: requires api key but free level available at the time of this writing; worked for me

Comment: Can just use empty string `''` as the API Key and `select1 works.

Answer (score 7):

After having the need myself to debug cron jobs,
I wrote the following script. 
It tries hard to simulate the exact same conditions as cron
before running a command (that includes a modified environment,
but it also has to do with non-interactive shells,
no attached terminal, etc.).

Call it with your command/script as argument, and you have an instant and painless way to debug your cron job.
It is also hosted (and possibly updated) on GitHub: [`run-as-cron.sh`](https://gist.github.com/daladim/7f67eb95d59aadc8f3e8cd66c6f235d3):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Run as if it was called from cron, that is to say:
#  * with a modified environment
#  * with a specific shell, which may or may not be bash
#  * without an attached input terminal
#  * in a non-interactive shell

function usage(){
    echo "$0 - Run a script or a command as it would be in a cron job," \
                                                       "then display its output"
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "   $0 [command | script]"
}

if [ "$1" == "-h" -o "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    usage
    exit 0
fi

if [ $(whoami) != "root" ]; then
    echo "Only root is supported at the moment"
    exit 1
fi

# This file should contain the cron environment.
cron_env="/root/cron-env"
if [ ! -f "$cron_env" ]; then
    echo "Unable to find $cron_env"
    echo "To generate it, run \"/usr/bin/env > /root/cron-env\" as a cron job"
    exit 0
fi

# It will be a nightmare to expand "$@" inside a shell -c argument.
# Let's rather generate a string where we manually expand-and-quote the arguments
env_string="/usr/bin/env -i "
for envi in $(cat "$cron_env"); do
   env_string="${env_string} $envi "
done

cmd_string=""
for arg in "$@"; do
    cmd_string="${cmd_string} \"${arg}\" "
done

# Which shell should we use?
the_shell=$(grep -E "^SHELL=" /root/cron-env | sed 's/SHELL=//')
echo "Running with $the_shell the following command: $cmd_string"


# Let's redirect the output into files
# and provide /dev/null as input
# (so that the command is executed without an open terminal
# on any standard file descriptor)
so=$(mktemp "/tmp/fakecron.out.XXXX")
se=$(mktemp "/tmp/fakecron.err.XXXX")
"$the_shell" -c "$env_string $cmd_string" > "$so" 2> "$se"  < /dev/null

echo -e "Done. Here is \033[1mstdout\033[0m:"
cat "$so"
echo -e "Done. Here is \033[1mstderr\033[0m:"
cat "$se"
rm "$so" "$se"
```

Comment: The "generate a string" bit is problematic and would be solved in a safer way with the help of `env`.

Comment: (1) If you don’t use any bash-isms, you can write your shebang as ``#!/bin/sh``.  But see point 9.  (2) You specifically allow and handle a command *and its arguments* to be passed as arguments to your `run-as-cron` script; you should say so in your Usage message.  On the other hand, there’s no real need or reason to talk about a command ***or*** a script — scripts *are* commands.  (3) You test `$1` for help options, which is good.  You should also check whether it is null (or missing). (4) `[ condition₁ -o condition₂ ]` is deprecated. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Use`[ condition₁ ] || [ condition₂ ]`. (Or you could use a `case` statement here.) (5) `whoami` is probably safe, but you should get into the habit of quoting all command substitutions: e.g., `"$(whoami)"`. (6) You define a variable `cron_env`, but then you use the literal string `/root/cron-env` (needlessly) two more times after that. (7) `sed` is a fairly powerful program; you generally don’t need to *combine* it with `grep`. You could set `the_shell` with`$(sed -n '/^SHELL=/ s///p' "$cron_env")`. (8) And, after setting `the_shell`, you should verify that it’s not null. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (9) You don’t actually need the curly braces in the ``env_string="${env_string} $envi "`` and ``cmd_string="${cmd_string} \"${arg}\" "`` commands.  (They don’t hurt, but you don’t need them.  See [${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does ….](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525))  Also, you could use `cmd_string+=…` — but note that this is non-POSIX, so, if you use it, you’ll need to keep the `#!/bin/bash` shebang.  (10) I agree with @Kusalananda: parsing `"$@"` is problematic and can be avoided.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (11) Also, parsing the output from `env` is unreliable and therefore dangerous.  Environment variable values can contain any character other than nul; your code does not handle the standard problematic characters, such as whitespace and quotes.  (12) Running a command with `< /dev/null` does not actually make it “executed without an attached terminal”.  (13) It might be useful to display the value of `$?` after the command runs.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (14) If you’re going to use terminal escape sequences, you should define them separately (e.g., `bold='\033[1m'`) as variables with descriptive names, and then use those variables in your `echo` / `printf` statement.  Ideally you should get their values dynamically; i.e., from something like `tput`.  (15) You have not taken into account the special meaning that `%` has in actual cron command lines.  (Don’t feel too bad; I would have overlooked that myself if not for [basic6’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42715/580656#comment826250_213302).)

Answer (score 5):

[Daladim's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580656/209677) was useful to me. It runs the command immediately, not after up to 59 seconds later as the "`* * * * *`" style answers do. It presents the output as soon as the command runs.

I have extended it a bit, adding the ability to run as any user, not just root, fixing some corner case bugs, and adding a specific message with instructions to bootstrap the environment to match cron.

I put it up [on GitHub](https://github.com/poleguy/run-as-cron.git).

Link a command called run-as-cron to this file from your path.

If you have a crontab entry like this:

```
0 0 * * * command.sh --option
```

test it like this:

```
run-as-cron command.sh --option
```

or as root:

```
sudo run-as-cron command.sh --option
```

or as some other user:

```
sudo su otheruser
run-as-cron command.sh --option
```

Note, that the very first time you run this as a user you'll need to add a command to `crontab -e` and wait a minute to grab the environment.

These questions and answers might also be useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984725/test-a-weekly-cron-job
- https://serverfault.com/questions/85893/running-a-cron-job-manually-and-immediately

Comment: (1) Please see my comments on [Daladim’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580656/80216); most of them also apply to yours.  (2) It’s good that you added attribution to your script (which is derived from Daladim’s), but it would be better if you also gave the original author credit *by name.*

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I've added the name Daladim to my github script. I will also look at the other comments you made when I can make time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are auto-generating your crontab you can do something like this:

```
    cat <<EOF >/tmp/mycrontab
# Run five minutes after midnight, every day - use bash to get PATH to include sbin so that ifconfig will work
5 0 * * *       bash -lc '$HOME/myscript.sh'
# run on restart - use bash to get PATH to include sbin so that ifconfig will work
@reboot         bash -lc '$HOME/myscript.sh'
# Installation time +1 min $(date -d +1min +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%d' ) - use bash to get PATH to include sbin so that ifconfig will work
$(date -d +1min +'%M %H %d %m %w')  bash -lc '$HOME/myscript.sh'
EOF
    crontab /tmp/mycrontab
```

This will make 'myscript.sh' run after midnight, at reboot and at installation time and properly at the same time 7 years from now if the month, day and weekday align again at that time.

Comment: That isn't what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the schedule to `* * * * *`.

That would be the easiest and most reliable solution.

Answer (score -1):

*I am quoting answer ([view fully](https://serverfault.com/a/532121/208540)) from serverfault*:

---

Execute crontab commands in-bulk :

```
crontab -l | grep -v '^#' | cut -f 6- -d ' ' | while read CMD; do eval $CMD; done
```

to run it under another user:

`sudo -H -u username bash -c "crontab... "`

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution that seems to be a little better for my purposes (commands shown for CentOS / RHEL-like, but should be adaptable basically anywhere).

This requires `libfaketime` - you can build it yourself from source at https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime or just use one of the many packages from https://pkgs.org/download/libfaketime.

1. Stop crond service - `service crond stop`
2. Figure out when your service *should* run by - https://crontab.guru is pretty useful for this.
3. Run crond in foreground mode through libfaketime's `faketime` tool (it lets you fake out the syscall for time lookups for any child processes).

   1. I wouldn't run this on a production server
   2. `faketime '2019-10-17 07:59:50' /usr/sbin/crond -n -x test,sch`

```
[root@user-crontesting-dvc-01 ~]# faketime '2019-10-17 07:59:50' /usr/sbin/crond -n -x sch
debug flags enabled: sch
[4841] cron started
log_it: (CRON 4841) INFO (Syslog will be used instead of sendmail.)
log_it: (CRON 4841) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 34% if used.)
log_it: (CRON 4841) INFO (running with inotify support)
[4841] GMToff=0
log_it: (CRON 4841) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
[4841] Target time=1571299200, sec-to-wait=11
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="/usr/libexec/myexc/crontesting.cron > /dev/null 2> &1"
[4841] Target time=1571299260, sec-to-wait=60
log_it: (root 4844) CMD (/usr/libexec/myexc/crontesting.cron > /dev/null 2> &1)
log_it: (root 4843) CMDOUT (/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&')
log_it: (root 4843) CMDOUT (/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `/usr/libexec/myexc/crontesting.cron > /dev/null 2> &1')
```

Answer (score -2):

Yea, you type the command and options directly into the CLI and run the job...

```
/bin/bash /some/script.sh --options
```

is just

```
$ ./some/script.sh --options
```

with a timer.

Comment: This is incorrect. First, the script to run is `/some/script.sh`, not `./some/script.sh`. While this is probably a mere typo, a more serious problem is the fact that the interactive user's environment is not the same as cron's environment. Several suggestions have already been made how to test the command in the correct environment; please consider deleting your answer.

Comment: @berndbausch: Maybe not ‘merely’ a typo; there’s a widespread [misconception](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196135/80216) that you need to use **``./``** to run a script, independent of location.

Comment: Wow, I have never heard of the "requirement" to put a dot at the beginning of a script's pathname. If that's true, it indicates a widespread and deep misunderstanding of UNIX filesystem principles. Let's correct it whenever we encounter it.

Comment: `/some/script.sh` is an absolute pathname. Meaning: The root directory contains a directory named `some`, where `script.sh` resides. `./some/script.sh` on the other hand means that directory `some` is located in the *current directory*, not root.

Comment: Assuming `script.sh` is indeed a Bash script, you can run it by handing it over to the interpreter, such as `bash /some/script.sh` or `bash ./some/script.sh`.

Comment: If `script.sh` has execution permissions, `/some/script.sh` or `./some/script.sh` can be run directly from the command line as-is. To complicate things a little, this assumes either that the interpreter is specified by a "hash-bang" clause in the first line of the script, or that the default shell is able to interpret the script.

Comment: Reviewing comments and it was not mentioned that ./script.sh syntax is used for running scripts in a present directory for a script that is not in one's PATH. It's obviously redundant and not needed to include a preceding . if you specify the absolute directory.