# Problems when trying to execute sh file from another sh file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -f "/path/pycharm.sh"; then sh ./pycharm.sh;
fi
```

I am trying to run **pycharm.sh** from a bash file and I've looked carefully to give all the permissions needed to the file. Unfortunately every time I run it I get this:

> Can't open ./pycharm.sh

Comment: What directory are you running the script from? Is it the same directory that `pycharm.sh` is in? Is that the entire error message?

Comment: No, it's not in the same directory. And yes, that's the entire message that I get. I need that script to be on my desktop so it won't help me if I put it in the same directory as `pycharm.sh`

Comment: It's strange that you use for the access to the file two different paths; once `/path/pycharm.sh` (absolute) and once `./pycharm.sh` (relative). If it's the same file then the path definitions should match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't use `./` to run a script *in general*,
you use it to run a program (script or compiled binary)
***in the current directory***. 
If the second script is in `/path/pycharm.sh`,
then you should run it as `/path/pycharm.sh`, and not `./pycharm.sh`.

Answer (score 6):

Your shell script is in another directory, use the absolute path.

```
sh /path/pycharm.sh
```

Comment: I need it called thru another bash file.

Comment: Yes, just remove `./` from the script and it should work.

Comment: @zer0rest; if you omit `./` then it's also assumed to be in the current directory. Whether you call it `sh ./somefile` or `sh somefile`, it's the same. There's only a differene if `somefile` is `chmod`ed as executable, then the `PATH` definition would matter in those two cases; the one without `./` would be searched through `PATH`.

Comment: @Janis; You're correct, I edited my answer. I just find it odd to run a script as `sh ./script` instead of just `sh script`.

Answer (score 5):

The error is fairly explicit:

- It either doesn't exist at the specified path, or
- It doesn't have the permission to open it.

As you're using a relative path, I'd put my money on the first. Specify a full path to your second `pycharm.sh` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute **pwd** command and check that file **pycharm.sh** is present in that directory.Or you can provide full path in a script.

You can have more detailed information by using option **-x** while executing script.

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something or do you mean to execute the very string whose existence you are checking first. If so, then the correct way is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -f "/path/pycharm.sh"; then /path/./pycharm.sh;
fi
```

Comment: What do you think you are adding to the multiple correct answers that have already been posted?  And why do you suggest inserting `/.` into the second pathname?