# How do I run my shell script from anywhere

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu Studio 16.10 64 bit.  I created  a shell script xyz.sh
the path to the file is home/somefolder/test/xyz.sh I have already added

```
`chmod u+x xyz.sh`
```

and I ran the script

```
./xyz.sh
```

It was successfull.

However, when I did a cd to go to my home directory and executed xyz.sh using

```
 ./xyz.sh
```

I got the message bash: ./xyz.sh: No such file or directory

Despite executing the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:home/somefolder/test/xyz.sh
```

Comment: You need to define the absolute path in `$PATH`, path to your script is missing a `/` at the beginning.

Comment: I have added I just missed it here that's it I just checked my history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems when trying to execute sh file from another sh file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196135/problems-when-trying-to-execute-sh-file-from-another-sh-file)

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Problems when trying to execute sh file from another sh file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196135/80216): don’t use `./xyz.sh` unless you’re in the directory where `xyz.sh` is located.

Answer (score 4):

If you've added the path correctly, you just need to call the name of the script, so `xyz.sh` rather than using `./xyz.sh`

By using `./` you telling your shell to look in the current working directory, and run xyz.sh from there.

--

Side note, you're missing a / from the beginning of your directory path, it should be `PATH=$PATH:/home/somefolder/test` and you should only add the directory, not the entire executable name.

Comment: When an answer has worked for you, you'd normally accept it, by hitting the the big tick.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly stating a path to an executable will make the shell try to use that path to execute the executable.

If saying `./myscript` and if `myscript` is not in the current directory, then you will get a "no such file or directory" error.  This does *not* use the `$PATH` variable.

The `$PATH` should be a `:`-delimited list of directories (not files) in which the shell will search for executables when no path is specified on the command line.  It is a potential security risk to add the current directory (`.`) to the `PATH` variable (see "[Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come)").

Another simple solution for when you just want to have access to a single executable outside of you ordinary `$PATH` is to use an alias:

```
alias myscript=/path/to/myscript
```

(this goes in your shell initialization file, probably `.bashrc` for `bash`).

You should specify the full absolute path to the executable in the alias.