# When should I use [ vs [[ in Bash (single vs double brackets)?

Tags: bash, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)

When should I use a single bracket? `[`

When should I use double brackets? `[[`

Are both POSIX compliant?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Single bracket is the traditional form, and is often implemented as an external command. Double bracket is a bash (and ksh and zsh) extension, is *not* in POSIX, and has the advantage of cleaner syntax (see below) and not using a separate process.

One of the syntax differences is that `<` and `>` operators (note: not standard POSIX) don't need to be escaped or quoted to avoid reading as a redirect operator. Also, `[` requires some tricks in case one of the strings might be empty or begin with a hyphen. This is why you see scripts do something like `[ "x$ASD" == xValue ]` whereas with bash they could simply use `[[ $ASD == Value ]]`. Note that the "x" trick is not strictly necessary with a POSIX-compliant command testing only one thing, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes) for more details about it.

[The bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) has for more information about the differences. This has also [been answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash) on another stack exchange site.

Comment: `[` doesn't have `<` or `>` operators.  If it does it's a nonportable shell extension.  The `x$var` workaround is also unnecessary with POSIX `[` - it might have been needed for ancient implementations that had weird parsing quirks, but POSIX `[` is very well defined for up to 4 arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Only [`[` (`test`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) is in POSIX.  You won't find `[[` specified in POSIX except as a [reserved word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) that implementations may use.  Bash does indeed use `[[` as an enhanced test operator, and if you are writing scripts targeted specifically for `bash`, always use `[[` because it is much more powerful than `[` and safer to use as well.  If, however, you are targeting POSIX `sh`, you need to use `[`, and make sure to quote arguments and not use more than 4 arguments to `[`.