# string and number comparsion in bash in test statements?

Tags: linux, bash

I am not sure about this comparison i am doing:

```
   if [ "$exit_status" -eq 0 ];then
   #some statements
   fi
```

is this correct way of comparing numbers or quotes make the variable `exit_status` a string
to be compared with 0.I don't know if this could fail in some scenario.

Comment: It is correct but if you are using Bash you should use ((...)). It is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See [Arithmetic Expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ "$exit_status" -eq 0 ]` is correct if $exit_status only contains digits, and you could just as well remove the quotes (as long as IFS doesn't contain digits).

If x is empty or unset, `[ "$x" -eq 6 ]` results in an error but `[[ "$x" -eq 6 ]]` doesn't:

```
$ x=; [ "$x" -eq 6 ]
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
$ unset x; [ "$x" -eq 6 ]
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
$ x=; [[ "$x" -eq 6 ]]
$ unset x; [[ "$x" -eq 6 ]]
$
```

Arithmetic operators strip whitespace:

```
$ [ '6 ' -eq $'\n\t6' ]; echo $?
0
```

Inside [[ the operands of arithmetic operators are arithmetic expressions, so for example `[[ 4 -eq 2+2 ]]` is true. Numbers that start with 0 are treated as octal numbers:

```
$ [[ 010 -eq 8 ]]; echo $?
0
$ [ 010 -eq 8 ]; echo $?
1
```

I often use = / == even for comparing integers. = and == are equivalent in bash inside both [[ and [. == and [[ are not defined by POSIX.

Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed inside [[. `[[ $x = $y ]]` treats y as a pattern but `[[ $x = "$y" ]]` treats y literally:

```
$ x=44; y='4*'
$ [[ $x = $y ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ $x = "$y" ]]; echo $?
1
```

Comment: More precisely, `[[...]]`'s `-eq` compares two arithmetic expressions, while `[`'s compares decimal integer constants only (but you can do `[ "$((6+6))" -eq "$((0xc))" ]` with the standard syntax for `[[ 6+6 -eq 0xc ]]`). While you're at using non-standard `ksh` extensions, it's better to do `(( exp1 == exp2 ))` to do arithmetic comparison. Note that `[[ "1 + 1" -eq "4 - 2" ]]` is not equivalent to `[[ 1 + 1 -eq 4 - 2 ]]` (which would be a syntax error), and `[[ $x*2 -eq $y*3 ]]` is not the same as `[[ x*2 -eq y*3 ]]` (for instance in cases where `$x` is `1+2`).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is correct.

Quotes in shells are for different purpose than in other languages. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65633/22565) for more details.

In shell, quotes are used to prevent the shell to treat some characters specially and to prevent some operations that the shell would otherwise perform upon some types of expansion (like in this case variable expansion).

Typically, in this case, you want `"$exit_status"` to be expanded to one argument to the `[` command that is the content of that varaible, so you need the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting numbers is of little use though. If the parameter value is a number then the quotes don't change anything and if it is not then the if is going to fail anyway. OK, not in every case:

```
exit_status="a = a -o 0"; [ "$exit_status" -eq 0 ] # returns false
exit_status="a = a -o 0"; [ $exit_status -eq 0 ] # returns true
```

This is due to `[` being a bash builtin but nonetheless a simple command whereas `[[` is a compound command that changes command line parsing.

Comment: You've got it backward. It's _not_ quoting numbers that is of little use. Not quoting a variable (even if you know for sure contains only decimal digits) still asks the shell to perform word splitting, filename generation and empty removal on it, and it would still be a problem if `$IFS` does happen to contain digits. Quoting variables  should always be the default. Only remove the quotes if you have a good reason to, like in the rare cases where you do need word splitting or filename generation.