# What does "FILENAME=$(echo $INFILE | grep -oE "[^/]+$") " mean?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, scripting

```
FILENAME=$(echo /root/Source/code/script.sh | grep -oE "[^/]+$")
```

I know that it would give me the file name from the file path here as `script.sh`. But can some one please explain me this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-o` means: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

`[^/]+$` means: Match as many chars as possible to the right which do not contain a slash. That's the file name without the leading directories.

Usually this is done with:

```
basename /root/Source/code/script.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's count the number of mistakes in:

```
FILENAME=$(echo $INFILE | grep -oE "[^/]+$")
```

1. [`echo` should not be used for arbitrary data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565). Depending on the implementation, it will fail if `$INFILE` starts with `-` or contains backslashes or both.
2. [Leaving a variable unquoted is the *split+glob* operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65633/22565). That will cause the above to fail for many possible values of `$INFILE`. Variables should never be left unquoted unless you've got a very good reason not to.
3. `grep` works on each line of it's input, while here you want it to do it only the whole string.
4. If `$INFILE` is `/some/dir/` or `/`, that will return the empty string instead of `dir` or `/`.
5. The `-o` option is GNU specific, so that will only work where `grep` is the GNU `grep`.
6. cosmetic/convention: All Upper-case variable names should be reserved for environment variables.
7. command substitution removes the trailing newline characters, so the above will not work if `$INFILE` ends in newline characters.

To get the base name of a file, there's a standard command for that:

```
filename=$(basename -- "$infile")
```

Or to avoid (7) above:

```
filename=$(basename -- "$infile"; echo .); filename=${filename%??}
```

Or, using shell expansion operators:

```
filename=${infile##*/}
```

(still has problem (4) above).

Answer (score 3):

`[^/]+$` is a Regular Expression for "One or more of any character that is not a slash, followed by the end of the tested string".  The string being tested is `/root/Source/code/script.sh`; the part of that string that matches the pattern is `script.sh`.  `grep -o` returns only the matching pattern and not the entire line which matched.