# Reading a named pipe: tail or cat?

Tags: pipe, cat, tail, fifo

I made a file descriptor using

```
mkfifo fifo
```

As soon as something is written to this pipe, I want to reuse it *immediately*. Should I use

```
tail -f fifo
```

or

```
while true; do cat fifo; done
```

?

They seem to do the same thing and I could not measure a difference in performance. However, when a system does not support inotify (Busybox, for example), the former needs to be

```
tail -f -s 0 fifo
```

But this eats up the CPU with 100% usage (test it out: `mkfifo fifo && busybox tail -f -s 0 fifo & echo hi>fifo` / cancel with `fg 1` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). So is the while-true-cat the more reliable solution?

Comment: Pipes are not seekable, and `tail -f` needs seekable input.  The behavior of `tail -f fifo` is undefined.  If `tail -f -s 0 fifo` works on some systems those systems are relying on nonstandard behavior.

Comment: @SatōKatsura, that's not true. `tail` works fine on fifos and is required to. `-s` is not standard though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `tail` alone works fine, but `tail -f` needs seekable input.

Comment: @SatōKatsura no. It doesn't.  There's no reason why it would want to seek. After it has output the last 10 lines, it just sits there waiting for more input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It needs seekable input to recover from input errors.  Among other things, `tail -f fifo` is supposed to be still reading after `echo foo >fifo`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura, I suggest you read the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) and the source code of one or two implementations. You can't have I/O error on a pipe. You don't want `tail` to _recover_ (whatever that means) from an I/O error  but bail out with an error message. `tail` doesn't need to `seek` to continue reading after `echo foo > fifo` (after which `tail` would see eof, not an I/O error), it just needs to `sleep(1)` and do a `read()` again afterwards (in a loop) (on Linux, it can avoid the polling with inotify), like for reg files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do:

```
cat fifo
```

Assuming no other process has opened the `fifo` for writing yet, `cat` will block on the `open()` system call. When another process opens the file for writing, a pipe will be instantiated and `open()` will return. `cat` will call `read()` in a loop and `read()` will block until some other process writes data to the pipe.

`cat` will see end-of-file (eof) when all the other writing processes have closed their file descriptor to the `fifo`. At which points `cat` terminates and the pipe is destroyed¹.

You'd need to run `cat` again to read what will be written after that to the `fifo` (but via a different pipe instance).

In:

```
tail -f file
```

Like `cat`, `tail` will wait for a process to open a file for writing. But here, since you didn't specify a `-n +1` to copy from the beginning, `tail` will need to wait until eof to find out what the last 10 lines were, so you won't see anything until the writing end is closed.

After that, `tail` will not close its fd to the pipe which means the pipe instance won't be destroyed, and will still attempt to read from the pipe every second (on Linux, that polling can be avoided via the use of `inotify` and some versions of GNU `tail` do that there). That `read()` will return with eof (straight away, which is why you see 100% CPU with `-s 0` (which with GNU `tail` means to not wait between `read()`s instead of waiting for one second)) until some other process opens the file again for writing.

Here instead, you may want to use `cat`, but make sure the pipe instance always stays around after it has been instantiated. For that, on most systems, you could do:

```
cat 0<> fifo # the 0 is needed for recent versions of ksh93 where the
             # default fd changed from 0 to 1 for the <> operator
```

`cat`'s stdin will be open for both reading and writing which means `cat` will never see eof on it (it also instantiates the pipe straight away even if there's no other process opening the `fifo` for writing).

On systems where that doesn't work, you can do instead:

```
cat < fifo 3> fifo
```

That way, as soon as some other process opens the `fifo` for writing, the first read-only `open()` will return, at which point the shell will do the write-only `open()` before starting `cat`, which will prevent the pipe from ever being destroyed again.

So, to sum up:

- compared to `cat file`, it would not stop after the first round.
- compared to `tail -n +1 -f file`: it would not do a useless `read()` every second after the first round, there would never be eof on the one instance of the pipe, there would not be that up to one second delay when a second process opens the pipe for writing after the first one has closed it.
- compared to `tail -f file`. In addition to the above, it would not have to wait for the first round to finish before outputting something (only the last 10 lines).
- compared to `cat file` in a loop, there would be only one pipe instance. The race windows mentioned in ¹ would be avoided.

---

¹ at this point, in between the last `read()` that indicates eof and `cat` terminating and closing the reading end of the pipe, there is actually a small windows during which a process could open the `fifo` for writing again (and not be blocked as there's still a reading end). Then, if it writes something after `cat` has exited and before another process opens the `fifo` for reading, it would get killed with a SIGPIPE.

Comment: awesome. you are good at explaining things. about `cat <>fifo`: `cat will never see eof on it`. I understand the instance stays open. But if another process writes an EOF to it, it should also arrive at `cat`, right? So it just prefers to ignore it since there is bidirectional piping going on? Thanks!

Comment: @Blauhirn, there's no such thing as _"writing an EOF to a pipe"_. You see EOF on a pipe when all the writers are gone, period. Maybe you're thinking of the `^D` termios setting. But that only applies to I/O to terminal devices, that is serial/pty character devices that have a _tty line discipline_ attached to them (and only in some mode of operation), not pipes, not socketpairs,  not regular files, not directories, not block devices, not other character devices.

Comment: @Blauhirn (continued), by opening the fifo in read+write mode, we have a fd to both ends of the pipe (not bidirectional; even on systems where regular pipes are bidirectional, named pipes have only one direction), so as there's always a fd at the other end (the same fd as the one we're reading from), we'll never see eof, as there's still a writer at the other end: us.

Answer (score 2):

Let me propose another solution. Pipe will be available for reading as long as some process will write on the second end. So you can create some fake `cat` in the background (or in another terminal), for example:

```
mkfifo fifo
cat >fifo &
cat fifo
```

Now you can write to fifo as long as you want, and when finish just kill current `cat` with <kbd>C-c</kbd>, and then `fg` to bring first `cat` from the background and finally <kbd>C-d</kbd> to stop it.

Comment: In POSIX shells and when not interactive, when you start a command in background, its stdin becomes `/dev/null`, so `cat` will exit just after starting. In shells that don't do that, and/or if run from an interactive shell in a terminal, `cat` will likely be suspended as it attempts to read from the terminal while not being in the foreground.