# Cannot write text in a file when using here-document

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, cat, here-document

This command doesn't seem to work in my script, how can I decide in which file I want this text, if I just create a file with the following command

```
touch $name
```

I want the text to be in the file `$name` that I just made in my script.

```
cat <<'EOF'
Data...
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat <<'EOF' >>"$name"
Data...
EOF
```

Comment: thanks that worked, can i also make an if structure for putting some part of text in there?

Comment: you could, by using `$( do something here )`, but I wouldn't. It gets indeciphrable/messy/incomprehensible quickly. Do the comparisons outside of the `here` document part and insert text there via variables for example or maybe better: compose the text bit by bit.

Comment: U mean in the file? for example `cat <<'EOF' >>$name
$(if (($read == yes)))...
EOF`

Comment: yeah, don't do it that way. Do `if ...; then echo "foo" >> $name; fi; cat << EOF ...`

Comment: `$name` needs to be quoted.  e.g. `"$name"`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65633/7696 for a good summary of why variables should (almost) always be quoted.

Comment: wow thanks that worked, but one more problem this sentence now comes first in my file with the if structure but it should come on the second line after another sentence is this possible?

Comment: post your code in a new question

Comment: I don't really understand how u mean?

Comment: oh no i have found it, I made my if structure behind the file, thanks man, but if I put "$name" as text in my file it just prints out "$name" is there another way to print out a name in the file text?

Comment: You are talking about something that doesn't work as it should however nobody can see that something that doesn't work as you are not showing us. How are we supposed to know what this something that doesn't work is and be able to help you? We are not clairvoyants.