# [ vs [[ : which one to use in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, control-flow, test

The zsh man page, in its section on `test` (aka `[`), explicitly advises against using it at all, and urges readers to use `[[` whenever possible.

The [relevant section](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) states:

> The command attempts to implement POSIX and its extensions where these are specified. Unfortunately there are intrinsic ambiguities in the syntax; in particular there is no distinction between test operators and strings that resemble them. The standard attempts to resolve these for small numbers of arguments (up to four); for five or more arguments compatibility cannot be relied on. Users are urged wherever possible to use the '`[[`' test syntax which does not have these ambiguities.

I think I've come across similar advice for bash, but as I scan over the bash man page I can't find any "official" recommendation there on which form (`[` or `[[`) to use.  (Maybe I missed it?)

> Is there any reason, *other than backward compatibility with "older shells"*, for using `[` in a bash script?  Or to put it differently, does bash keep `[` along with `[[` for reasons *other* than backward compatibility?

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between [[ $a == z* \]\] and [ $a == z* \]?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674/22565)

Comment: Dang, usually the stackexchange interface saves me from posting duplicates, but this time it didn't: it showed exactly 0 suggestions for similar questions, which is pretty unusual, and maybe for this reason made me a bit over-confident...  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to prefer `[` over `[[` if sufficient is that `[` is more stable between the different bash versions.

See `man bash`:

> compat31
>
> If set, bash changes its behavior to that of version 3.1 with respect to quoted arguments to the [[ conditional command's =~ operator.
>
> compat32
>
> If set, bash changes its behavior to that of version 3.2 with respect to locale-specific string comparison
>   when using the [[ conditional command's < and > operators.  Bash versions prior to bash-4.1 use ASCII collation and strcmp(3); bash-4.1 and later use the current locale's collation sequence and strcoll(3).
>
> compat40
>
> If set, bash changes its behavior to that of version 4.0 with respect to locale-specific string comparison
>   when using the [[ conditional command's < and > operators (see previous item) and the effect of interrupting a command list.

Maybe it is also a little bit more common to users with `ksh` background.

#### Note about performance

'[[' is quicker as '['

- For a singular invocation the speed difference has **no commensurable impact**, and your should prefer the '[' builtin.
- If you it inside a bigger loop construct, you may think of replace '[' with '[['

For a measurement you may use the following compare script

```
let upperBound=$1
echo "check [,  ${upperBound} iterations"
let i=0
time while [ $i -lt ${upperBound} ] ; do let i++ ; done

echo; echo;
echo "check [[, ${upperBound} iterations"
let i=0
time while [[ $i < ${upperBound} ]] ; do let i++ ; done
```

**Result of compare script**

> check [,  1000 iterations
>
> real    0m0.031s
>   user    0m0.028s
>   sys     0m0.004s
>
> check [[, 1000 iterations
>
> real    0m0.000s
>   user    0m0.000s
>   sys     0m0.000s

Comment: += And the reason to not use it — it's slower then (again) built-in version `[[`.

Comment: I am not sure it makes much sense to select between `[` and `[[` based on _execution speed_, considering that Bash is an interpreted language that shouldn't really be used for performance-critical applications anyway. YMMV of course, but consider the wisdom of "Preliminary optimization is the root of all evil" (D. Knuth.)

Answer (score 5):

There are some subtle differences though:

```
#!/bin/bash

eg=whatever

if [ $eg == what* ]; then   # file glob test
    echo '[]'
fi

if [[ $eg == what* ]]; then   # pattern match test
    echo "[[]]"
fi
```

Unless there is a file called "whatever" in the current directory, the first test will not pass, because the match is against a file glob of the current directory contents, whereas the second one is an actual string pattern match.