# bash [[ = ]] behaviour

Tags: bash

`man bash`:

> [[ expression ]]
>   [...]
>   Expressions are composed of the primaries  described below  under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS. Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]];
>   [...]
>   When the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern Matching.

In the whole section the case of a single `=` is not mentioned.

> CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
>   [...]
>   string1 == string2
>   string1 = string2
>   True if the strings are equal. = should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.

From this description I would expect that

```
[[ a = $cmpstring ]]
```

checks for equal strings and

```
[[ a == $cmpstring ]]
```

checks for a pattern match. But that is not the case:

```
> [[ a == ? ]]; echo $?
0
> [[ a = ? ]]; echo $?
0
> [[ a == "?" ]]; echo $?
1
```

Do I misunderstand something or has the bash man page just forgotten to mention `=`?

Comment: Aren't `*` and `?` treated literally when in quotes (globbing is prevented)? So the test results look right to me. (`0` is success.)

Comment: Yes, they are muru

Comment: And while POSIX only specifies one of `=` and `==` (I don't remember which), they're synonyms in Bash.

Comment: POSIX requires `=`

Comment: So what's the question here, again?

Comment: @don_crissti That's what the [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc18) says as well. The [GNU manual's content](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-commands_002c-conditional) looks similar to what Hauke's posted (so presumably what `info bash` would say).

Comment: @don_crissti That's it I guess. Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: The way I interpret this is that `=` and `==` are both used for "string equality" (ref [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)) but within `[[...]]`, they do pattern matching instead (ref [conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs))

Comment: And be careful using `[...]` because glob chars will perform filename expansion instead.

Comment: @glennjackman I am not a native speaker but what do you take that from? That section mentions `==` but not `=`.

Comment: @muru - agreed but the online manual is 4-years old and pertains to bash 4.2 (`Edition 4.2, last updated 28 December 2010, of The GNU Bash Reference Manual, for Bash, Version 4.2`).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I'm assuming, from CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, that `==` and `=` have the same implementation. Pure assumption.

Comment: I think I'm right: lines 394 and 448 of http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/test.c#n385

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72042

Comment: I wonder if a bug should be filed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=` is the same as `==` when inside `[[...]]`. As per the more recent `man` page, under `SHELL GRAMMAR` > `Compound Commands` > `[[ expression ]]`:

```
The = operator is equivalent to ==
```

and further down, under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`:

```
string1 == string2
string1 = string2
        True  if  the  strings  are equal.  = should be used with the test command
        for POSIX conformance. When used with the [[ command, this performs pattern
        matching as described above (Compound Commands).
```

`bash info` page:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot of a `man` page? Really?

Comment: @jasonwryan My bad! Looks like the `info` docs are updated more often than the auto-generated online docs.