# can't figure out error in shell script unexpected operator

Tags: shell-script

$ sh backup-to-s3.sh

```
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
backup-to-s3.sh: 11: [: bkup_20151106_150532.zip: unexpected operator
```

ubuntu@accretive-staging-32gb-ephemeral:~$ cat backup-to-s3.sh

```
#Script to move /home/ubuntu/backup folder  to S3://auto-backup
#Author Ashish Karpe
cd /mnt/backup
filename="bkup_$(date +%Y%m%d_)"
/bin/ls -alF | awk '{ print $9 }'  > /tmp/file

for i in $(cat /tmp/file); do
#       echo $i;
#       read a;
#       echo $filename;
        if [ $filename* = $i ]
        then
                echo "Copying " $i "to S3://auto-backup";
                s3cmd put $i s3://auto-backup

            fi

done
```

Comment: Do you need to support filenames with spaces in their name, or not?

Comment: no spaces required in file name

Comment: I want to compare bkup_20151106_171600.zip with bkup_20151106_*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. don't use `for` to iterate over the lines of a file, use

   ```
   while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < filename
   ```
2. you don't need to pipe `ls` output to a file at all, **especially** using `-F`
3. use bash `[[ x == y ]]` for pattern comparisons, and the pattern is on the right-hand side:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/backup
prefix="bkup_$(date +%Y%m%d_)"

for file in * .*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue    # skip things like directories and soft links
    if [[ $file == $prefix* ]]; then
        echo "Copying " $file "to S3://auto-backup";
        s3cmd put $file s3://auto-backup
    fi
done < /tmp/file
```

Comment: What are you talking about with `[[ x == y ]]` "for pattern comparisons". That's not in any manual I have. Maybe you are using a different shell?

Comment: @Otheus - see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178035/22142)

Comment: @don_crissti Perhaps you misunderstood my problem with Glenn's statement. It's that you should `use [[ x == y ]] for *pattern comparisons*`. Your link only confirms to me that this is either wrong or misleading at best.

Comment: It's [documented right in the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b): `When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching`

Comment: For example, test if a string contains a vowel: `if [[ $str == *[aeiou]* ]]; then echo Yes; else echo No; fi`. Equivalent to `case "$str" in *[aeiou]*) echo Yes;; *) echo No;; esac`

Comment: does `-f .. ||` actually skip symlinks? it will also skip nodes or pipes. and `case` should probably be preferred to `[[ ... ]]`. it can handle more than a single decision path, is shell-portable, and almost always leads to cleaner scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you are dumping the output of 'ls' into a file and parsing that you are indirectly parsing the output of 'ls' which is either problematic, a really bad idea or WRONG!!! depending on who you ask.

Here is [why you shouldn't parse the output of 'ls'](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

Here is [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html)!

For instance if one the files has a '-' (dash/hyphen) in the filename which is not escaped (by prefixing it with a backslash ('\')) it might be interpreted as a parameter.

Avoiding parsing 'ls' may be as simple as;

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*"
.
./dont_parse_ls.sh
./array.dat
./.bashrc
./BASH.Indirect.Reference.sh
./basharray.sh
./.forever
```

Which comes out the same as

```
/bin/ls -alF | awk '{ print $9 }'

./
../
.bashrc
.forever/
BASH.Indirect.Reference.sh
array.dat
basharray.sh*
dont_parse_ls.sh
```

## YMMV

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 major problems in the script. Your fundamental problem is the snippet:

```
if [ $filename* =
```

There are a few problems with this. First, in shell-scripting, you cannot "glob" a match pattern. Well, you can, but if the fileglob results in more than one match, you will get both of them, in which case the "[" program (yes, it's a program) will attempt to evaluate:

```
filename1 filename2 filename3 = $i
```

It works if and only if the fileglob expands to exactly one filename, and you can rarely guarantee that. In your case, $filename expands to at least one file, but you should be aware that's not always the case. If "$file*" expands to no file at all, you might (depending on a shopt setting) get the empty string:

```
= $i
```

which will cause the `[` to fail. With the right shopt, however, you instead get:

```
backup-2014-whatever* = $i
```

With the `*` being part of the comparison.

The second fundamental problem is use of the `-F` parameter in `ls`. This tells ls to append to the filename one of several characters, depending on if the file is an executable, soft-link, etc.

NetScr1be is onto something, but look, you don't have to follow NetScr1be's advice and never use `ls`... just don't use `ls -l`. Instead, use `ls -1` which will print only the names of the files in a single-column, no frills. (For very large directories, it will sort them, and this may be a problem, in which case there is a no-sort option; or use find.)

To be more secure, your variables should be double-quoted, and both LHS and RHS prefixed with a dummy character, in order to make sure weird filenames that begin with a `-` don't throw it off.

I would use Glenn's advice, more or less, and do it this way:

```
command ls -1 | while read file; do
    if [ x"$file" = x"$filename" ]]; then 
        echo Do Work Here
    fi
done
```

That's how I *would* do it, but Glenn's kindly informed me, I really should do it *his* way:

```
for file in *; do 
    if [[ $file == $filename ]]; then ...
```

Comment: I alias `ls` to `ls -F`, so you'd better do `command ls | ...`, but that's not the correct way to iterate over files. use `for file in *`

Comment: You're right: `command ls` is the way to go. There are problems with `for file in *` because files may include whitespace. Though in theory you save yourself a fork.

Comment: bash `[[ ... ]]` does not perform word splitting or glob expansion ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b)), so the quotes and the `x` are not required

Comment: files with whitespace is precisely why you use `for`. Even filenames with newlines are handled correctly. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Holy cow, when did they fix that!?! (the `for` thing). Many many thanks. (I was a bash 1.2 user).

Answer (score 1):

This script does everything.  Why not this?  The shell will select the correct files for you so no need to call `ls`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /mnt/backup/bkup_$(date +%Y%m%d)_*
do
    s3cmd put "$file" s3://auto-backup
done
```

- The only external command is `s3cmd`.
- No `if` statements.
- The only decision point is the `for` loop.
- Easy to read.