# Variable comparison inside if in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris

I'm trying to compare two variables inside an if condition:

```
#!/bin/bash
Jump="/home/Lists/srv"
S=`echo "$1" | perl -ne 'print lc'`
J1=`grep $S $Jump |awk '{print $1}'`
grep $S $Jump >> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
 then
   if [ "$S" == "$J1" ]
   then
     echo "$S" is equal to "$J1" :
     ssh -qt $S "$2"
   else
     echo "$S" is not equal to "$J1"
     ssh -qt $J1 "ssh -qt $S $2"
   fi
  else 
    ssh -qt $S "$2"
  fi
```

Whenever I try to execute it always goes to else condition. and executes `echo "$S" is not equal to "$J1"`

I'm executing this script as `./test.sh` followed by a server name for ex:

```
./test.sh hostname1
```

It should then lower the case and put it in variable `S`, and search for `$S` in the file `Jump="/home/Lists/srv"`. If it finds there it should grep the first column and put it in another variable `J1`. Now, if value of `S` and `J1` are similar, then it should ssh to `$S` else (1st) it should first ssh to `$J1` and then ssh to `$S`. Else (2nd) if it doesn't find `$S` in Jump file it should directly ssh `$S`.

While I'm executing it directly goes to 1st else condition. even if `$S` and `$J1` are similar.

Comment: Yes I'm actually using it like that a=hello and b=hi. that was a typing miss. There is no space and no $ while declaring variables. Please advice...

Comment: Well, the strings `hello` and `hi` are not equal. Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/whats-the-diference-between-comparison-inside-if-using-two-or-a-single-equal?rq=1

Comment: For the updated question: You will have to explain how you call this script and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I'm executing this script as ./test.sh followed by a server name for ex: ./test.sh hostname1

Comment: I'm executing this script as ./test.sh followed by a server name for ex: ./test.sh hostname1    It should then lower the case and put it in variable 'S', and search for 'S' in the file  Jump="/home/Lists/srv" if it finds there it should grep the first column and put it in another variable J1. Now, if  value of 'S' and 'J1' are similar, then it should ssh to 'S' else (1st) it should first ssh to J1 and then ssh to S. Else (2nd) if it doesn;t find 'S' in Jump file it should directly  ssh 'S'. While Im executing it directly goes to 1st else condition. even if S and J1 are similar

Comment: Replace `==` with `=`  in the test of the two strings

Comment: Yes, I just tried by replacing == with =, and it still fails with same 1st else condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description of what you're trying to achieve, the following may be a script that does that:

```
#!/bin/bash

server="${1,,}"

jumphost="$( awk -vs="$server" '$0 ~ s { print $1; exit }' "/home/Lists/srv" )"

if [[ -z "$jumphost" ]] || [[ "$jumphost" == "$server" ]]; then
    ssh -qt "$server" "$2"
else
    ssh -qt "$jumphost" "ssh -qt \"$server\" \"$2\""
fi
```

The parameter expansion `${1,,}` will lower-case the value of `$1`. For older versions of `bash`, use the following instead:

```
server="$( printf '%s' "$1" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' )"
```

The `jumphost` variable will be set to whatever is in the first column of the first line in the file `/home/Lists/srv` matching the name of the server.  Note that this only picks out the *first* match in the file and that the match is taking the *whole* line into consideration.

If the match should be only against the second column, change `$0` to `$2` in the Awk script.

If `$jumphost` is empty, or if it's the same as `$server`, then the first branch will be taken, otherwise the second.

**An explanation of the Awk script was requested:**

```
jumphost="$( awk -vs="$server" '$0 ~ s { print $1; exit }'
```

With `-v` one sets an Awk variable to a specific value.  In the command above, we set the Awk variable `s` to the value of `$server`. This variable is then available within the Awk script.

In the Awk script,

```
$0 ~ s { print $1; exit }
```

the code within `{ ... }` will be executed whenever the condition `$0 ~ s` is true.  The condition `$0 ~ s` means "`$0` matches (the regular expression) `s`". The variable `s` is what we gave the value of `$server` just before, and `$0` is the contents of the current record (line) that Awk has just read.  So in short, this finds a line in the file that contains the server name.

To force an exact match on the second column (for example), one could instead use `$2 == s` as the condition.

The code in `{ ... }` will print `$1`, which is the first field (column) of `$0` (the line), before it exits the script.  I'm choosing to exit so that we don't end up matching more than a single line.  If the user specifies a too vague value for `$server`, we run the risk of matching multiple lines otherwise.

Finally, the value outputted by Awk will be assigned to the shell variable `jumphost` through `$( ... )`, which is roughly the same as `` `...` ``.

Comment: it fails with : ./test.sh: line 2: ${1,,}: bad substitution
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using. What is the output of `/bin/bash --version`?

Comment: It's GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @VikasThakur Use `server="$( printf '%s' "$1" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' )"` instead of `server="${1,,}"` in that case.  I have updated the answer with this information.

Comment: @VikasThakur On Solaris, you might also want to use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of just `awk`.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!! it works.... Would really appreciate if you could just explain me this part:  jumphost="$( awk -vs="$server" '$0 ~ s { print $1; exit }'.

Comment: @VikasThakur I've added an explanation to my answer.