# "==" logical operator and zsh version 5.7.x (installed using Homebrew)

Tags: osx, zsh, test

Been getting errors on my scripts when using this operator. I've  some online documentation and double equals should supposedly work. Any ideas?

Zsh reference guide: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html

Script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

if [ $_user == "root" ]; then
    echo "root"
else
    echo "not root"
fi
```

Running it:

```
$ ./script.sh
./script.sh:3: = not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between single and double equal signs (=) in shell comparisons?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-equal-signs-in-shell-compari)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: a `==` is a **logical operator** only inside `[[ … ]]` constructs.

```
$ [[ one == one ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

And it works also in ksh and bash.

When used outside a `[[ … ]]` construct a [=cmd becomes a **filename expansion operator** but only in zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion)

```
$ echo ==
zsh: = not found
```

That is what happens inside the simpler `[ … ]` construct you used.

But the correct way to test that the user running the shell script is root is to do:

```
if (( EUID == 0 )); then
    echo "root"
else
    echo "not root"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

[`=cmd` is a filename expansion operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion) in `zsh` that expands to the path of the `cmd` (resolved by a lookup of `$PATH`). If no such command is found, that results in a fatal error like when globs don't match.

So `==` here in an argument of that `[` command is asking the shell to lookup the `=` command in `$PATH` and `zsh` is telling you there's no such `=` anywhere in there.

```
$ echo =ls
/bin/ls
$ echo ==
zsh: = not found
$ install -m 755 /dev/null ~/bin/=
$ echo ==
/home/stephane/bin/=
```

Here, either use the standard syntax for the `[` command:

```
[ "$_user" = root ]
```

Or quote the `=`:

```
[ "$_user" '==' root ]
```

You'd need the quotes for regex matching as well:

```
[ "$_user" '=~' '^ro+t$' ]
```

In any case, you'd want to  quote `$_user` or you'd get some confusing error  when `$_user` is empty or unset (and worse including an arbitrary command injection vulnerability in Korn-like shells other than `zsh` (like `bash`)).

You can also disable that feature by disabling the `equals` option (`set +o equals`) which is not very useful in scripts.

Or use the `ksh`-style `[[...]]` construct:

```
[[ $_user = root ]]
[[ $_user == root ]]
[[ $_user =~ '^ro+t$' ]]
```

Or a `case` construct:

```
case $_user in
  (root) ...
esac
```

(`[[ = ]]`, `[[ == ]]` and `case` do pattern matching (wildcard, not regexp))

Note those are conditional expression, there's no need to disambiguate between an assignment and equality operator, so no need for a `==` operator.

Comment: If the code is supposed to check whether the current user is root or not, it would additionally be better to do that using the `id` utility.

Comment: @Kusalananda, in `zsh`, you'd rather use `$USERNAME` or `$LOGNAME` (or better `((EUID == 0))` if it's a check for sufficient privileges)

Comment: Those are reset when entering a script? (`LOGNAME` doesn't seem to be, but `USERNAME` is).

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, they're mapped to the process attributes, you can also modify them to change euid/uid...

Answer (score 2):

A shorter answer at a tangent ..perhaps you read a sample created for running under another shell type?

```
$ zsh -c 'if [ "x" == "x" ]; then echo "equal!"; fi'
zsh:1: = not found

$ bash -c 'if [ "x" == "x" ]; then echo "equal!"; fi'
equal!
```

Comment: OP added the zsh reference guide info after the fact. However, the example might be relevant for others so leaving.