# Is there a reason to quote the exit status $? variable?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I was looking at Google's style guides for their bash scripts, and saw that they quote the exit status variable **$?** [here](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml?showone=Loops#Loops).

```
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then
    error_message
fi
```

I thought return values are always numeric, so is there any reason to ever quote them?

Is it just a good habit to get into (because you want to quote other special shell variables like "$@")?

Comment: Try `IFS=0; echo $?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Highly recommend**

You should read this [wonderful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/38906) for more details.

---

Setting `IFS` contains digit can break your code:

```
$ IFS=0
$ echo test
$ [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo done
bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

Some shells may inherit `IFS` from environment (`dash`, `ash`), some don't (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`). But someone can control the environment, your script will break anyway (`$#`, `$!` are also affected).

A note, in your example, you used new test `[[...]]`, so field splitting is turned off, you don't need to quote in this case. It will be matter if you use old test `[...]`.

```
$ IFS=0
$ echo test
$ [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo done
done
```

Comment: Ahhh IFS, I see. Thanks. That other answer you linked is fantastic too.

Comment: Long story, short: if it is a variable in shell, you should probably always quote it.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you don't *need* to quote the left-hand side within `[[ ... ]]`.
But as [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) put it in comments on his [beautiful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/17433),
there's no compelling reason not to quote it, so just do it and sleep better at night. It's a good recommended practice, less doubts and questions asked.

In old-style `[ ... ]` you *must* quote, you don't have a choice.
In any case you shouldn't use old-style `[ ... ]` anymore,
the new style `[[ ... ]]` is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks also janos, that answer by Stéphane is a great read.

Comment: Thanks, I don't agree one should prefer `[[...]]` over `[...]` though. See also [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674)