# Similar test expressions using or operator?

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

Just wondering if this:

```
if [ "$first_arg" == "major" ] || [ "$first_arg" == "minor" ]; then
        exit 1;
fi
```

is the same as this:

```
if [ "$first_arg" == "major" || "$first_arg" == "minor" ]; then
      exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: You don't need the double quotes with `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @choroba thanks, even if I quote one expression but not the other, you are saying that `[[...]]` will quote everything for me?

Comment: There's simply no word splitting nor pathname expansion in `[[ ... ]]`. See the end of my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same. In fact `[ "$first_arg" == "major" || "$first_arg" == "minor" ]` is not even a valid expression.

This is because `[` is a command that's equivalent to `test` and they can't use the `||` alternative, which operates on the inter-command level. What could be historically considered correct for alternative is `-o`, but [it's now marked as obsolete by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)<sup>1</sup>, which advises to rewrite

```
test "$1" -o "$2"
```

into

```
test "$1" || test "$2"
```

Apart from the `test` and `[` constructs, there's also the "modern" `[[` test command, which in turn doesn't accept `-o` altogether, but instead accepts `||`.

Thus all of these are valid and equivalent:

1. One `[[` test:

   ```
   if [[ $first_arg == major || $first_arg == minor ]]; then
       exit 1;
   fi
   ```
2. Two `[[` tests:

   ```
   if [[ $first_arg == major ]] || [[ $first_arg == minor ]]; then
       exit 1;
   fi
   ```
3. Two `[` tests (the standard equivalent):

   ```
   if [ "$first_arg" = major ] || [ "$first_arg" = minor ]; then
       exit 1;
   fi
   ```

Double quotes aroung `$first_arg` are not necessary inside `[[`, as there's no word splitting nor pathname expansion in there. The quotes should be used with `[`, however. And there's no point in quoting `minor` nor `major` either. Not just here, but with `test` or `[` too. That's because they're simple strings.

<sub>1. See APPLICATION USAGE.</sub>

Comment: Also, `==` is not (generally) valid in `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270847/never-use-the-a-or-o-operator-with

Comment: So in other words: both expressions are not valid -)

Comment: Bash's documentation has `==` and `=` equivalent for string comparison. Though it states that `= should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.`

Comment: @Tomasz, yeah, Bash isn't too picky with that, and neither is the `[` command from GNU coreutils. Dash doesn't like `==`, though, and there's no advantage to using it.

Comment: Also: `case $first_arg in (major|minor) exit 1; esac`  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your expressions are not valid, there is a quasi equivalence ;-)

Note that `==` is only valid with the non-standard `[[` oparator.

In general: when using the `test` builtin, it is recommended to use only simple expressions as larger expressions could result in unpredictable results in case that parameter expansion applies.

Since the `test` is built into the shell since approx. 35 years, calling more simple `test` commands and combine them at shell level is not a performance problem anymore.

Comment: `==` is accepted by Bash in `[`, but that's not POSIX compliant.

Comment: I know there's issues with `-a`/`-o` in `[`/`test`, but I do wonder what you refer to with macro expansion?

Comment: macro expansion if the official wording for shell variable expansion.

Comment: i guess they are semantically invalid

Comment: @schily, Can you tell me what texts use that phrase? All documentation for the shells I've looked at talk about parameter expansion or substitution, as do the Open Group specifications I've seen.

Comment: You are correct, sorry