# shell script: too many arguments

Tags: shell-script, ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
i=1   
while [ "$i" -lt 121 ]   
do  
    if [ $i -lt 100 ]  
    then  
        if [ $i -lt 10 ]   
        then   
            i=00$i   
        else   
            i=0$1    
        fi   
    fi   
    echo "fla${i}"  
    i=' expr $i+1 '  
done  
exit 0
```

Why does this script result in an error "Too many arguments"?

Comment: This is [Bash Pitfall #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D), (save that link, you'll need it if you face other issues with shell programming. You had ksh instead of bash but many parts will apply). Also see the [difference between `[` and `[[`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56655/170373)

Comment: You can use `set -x` to the shebang line to enable verbose debug mode to see what exactly is happening while executing the script.

Comment: This can replace your script: `for i in {1..128}; do printf "fla%03d\n" $i; done`

Comment: Even simpler: `printf "fla%03d\n" {1..128}`

Answer (score 2):

`i=' expr $i+1 '` is not incrementing `i`, it assigns `i` a value of ' expr $i+1 '.

On the next iteration of the loop you run `[ $i -lt 100 ]`. Since `i` is not embraced in double quotes, this expands to `[ expr '$i+1' -lt 100 ]`.  `[` is actually a command, and you have given it too many arguments due to the reason above.

If you replace `i=' expr $i+1 '` with `i=$(($i + 1))`, your code should work.

Edit:

It seems that at least Bash will have issues with the number 008, it interprets it as octal.  You need to assign `00$i`, `0$i` and `$i` to another variable (or `echo "fla00$i"` etc) if you get some error after 008.

In this case, you'll need to do something when i >= 100.

This is what I would do:

```
i=1
while [ $i -lt 121 ]; do
    if [ $i -ge 100 ]; then
        echo fla$i
    elif [ $i -ge 10 ]; then
        echo fla0$i
    else
        echo fla00$i
    fi
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Comment: Try `elif` instead of `else if`

Comment: @glennjackman: That sure would look nicer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire script intention is to do exactly this: `seq -f 'fla%03.0f' 1 128`

As to the shell programming:

`i=0$1` should probably become `i="0$i"`

`' expr $i+1 '` should become `$( expr "$i" + 1 )`

Note the spaces required by `expr`. This won't work `$( expr "$i"+1 )`

Comment: Or `printf 'fla%03d\n' {1..121}` (or in `bash zsh` just `printf '%s\n' fla{001..121}` )

Comment: don't call out to expr, do `i=$((i+1))` or `((i++))` and let ksh handle the addition

Comment: The range is 1...120.