# Iterate over files and exclude the ones with certain name pattern Shell

Tags: shell, posix

How to iterate over files in the current directory and exclude some files having specific name patters? The solution must be POSIX compatible.

Assume the files to exclude follow the patterns: test[0-9].txt and work-.* (using regex).

The code I have so far:

```
for file in * 
do 
    if test "$file" != "test[0-9].txt" -o "$file" != "work-.*"
    then 
        echo "$file"
    fi 
done
```

At the moment the output is all files in the working directory. I'm pretty sure pattern matching in test is incorrect, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a string with all possible combinations:

```
all=:
for thing in *test[0-9].txt work-.*; do
    all=$all$thing:
done
if [[ "$all" == *:"$file":* ]]; then
    # it is in the list
```

Comment: That for goes in or before the other for, by the way, and doesn't replace it.

Comment: This is not POSIX code, as requested by the user in the question.  It also fails on filenames that contains certain combinations of valid filename characters.

Comment: `"*:$file:*"` treats `*` literally, not as a pattern matching character. It should be `*:$file:*` (with no quotes). Also (as Kusalananda pointed out), try with `touch a:work-.f work-.:a work-.f` (`a:work-.f` is also matched).

Comment: @fra-san, or rather, `*:"$file":*`

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, good point. (Even though word splitting and filename expansion are not performed in `[[` `]]`, the expansion of the unquoted `$file` will still be used as a pattern).

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if test "$file" != "test[0-9].txt" -o "$file" != "work-.*"
```

The `test` utility doesn't do pattern matching. For that, you need the Ksh/Bash/Zsh `[[ ]]` construct (and at least in Bash, the pattern needs to be not quoted). So:

```
for file in *; do 
    if [[ "$file" != test[0-9].txt && "$file" != work-.* ]]; then 
        echo "$file"
    fi 
done
```

would print `hello.txt`, if it exists, but not `test1.txt` or `work-.foo`.

Note that you need *and* instead of *or* there, as (x ≠ a *or* x ≠ b) would match any x.

See:

- [What is the difference between [[ $a == z* ]] and [ $a == z* ]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56655/170373)
- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373)

In strict POSIX sh, you'd need to use `case` to do the pattern match:

```
for file in *; do 
    case $file in
        test[0-9].txt|work-.*) false;;
        *) echo "$file";;
    esac
done
```

Note that if you want to match multiple digits after `test`, as in `test123.txt`, then you'll need ksh style extended globs and `test+([0-9]).txt` (and `shopt -s extglob` in Bash to have them work in all contexts). Though like Kusalananda notes, if you go that way, you may as well do:

```
for file in !(test[0-9].txt|work-.*); do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Also, using `ksh` globbing: `printf '%s\n' !(test[0-9].txt|work-.*)`  (untested)