# Test -n gives unexpected result

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, string, test

I understand `test -n <expression>` to return false if the expression evaluates to a string length of greater than 0.  Why then does the following happen?

```
Macbook:~ echo ${#undeclared_variable}
0
Macbook:~ test -n $undeclared_variable && echo Foo
Foo
```

Bash 4.x

My expectation is that since `test -n $undeclared_variable` should evaluate false, that Foo should not be echoed.  If I use `[[  ]]` instead of test, it works as expected.

Comment: See also [using single or double bracket - bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash/32227#32227) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to quote your variables. Without quotes you are writing `test -n` instead of `test -n <expression>`. The `test` command has no idea that you provided a variable that expanded to nothing.

In the syntax of POSIX shells like `bash`, `$VARIABLE` outside of double quotes is the “split+glob” operator: the value of the variable is split into a list of whitespace-delimited words, and each word is interpreted as a wildcard pattern and replaced by the names of matching files (or left alone if there is no matching file). If the value of the variable is empty, the list of words after splitting is an empty list. To obtain the value of the variable without further processing, the variable expansion needs to be inside double quotes.

The reason `[[` works is because it's a bash special syntax and not a command; within this special syntax, `$VARIABLE` means “value of `VARIABLE`” (except on the right-hand side of the pattern matching operators `=`, `==`, `!=` and `=~`). Using `[` would function the same as `test`. The following does what you want:

```
test -n "$undeclared_variable" && echo "Foo"
```

Comment: Could you explain why test does not recognize that a variable was passed to the test command when not using quotes?

Comment: When not using quotes, it is equivalent to `test -n`, which returns true.

Comment: i understand, I want to know the mechanism behind that behavior, is it Bash's wordspliting, or quoting behaviors that are responsible, or is it the test command that makes the non-quoted variable string "disappear"?

Comment: `[[` is special in `bash`. But for arbitrary commands, like `test`, an unquoted undefined variable is replaced by nothing (no arguments), while `"$undefined_variable"` is replaced by an argument that is the empty string (length = 0).

Comment: Note that you have the same behavior if the variable contains only spaces. This is just a consequence to word splitting in the particular case of 0 words.

Comment: Why does `test -n` evaluate true anyhow?  I would think it would be false if passed nothing.

Comment: Why does `test -n` evaluate to true? This explains it best: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400895/306023