# Why isn't [ -n ] false like [ -n "" ]?

Tags: bash

My question is on return values produced by this code:

```bash
if [ -n ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
```

This prints `true`.

Its complementary test using `[ -z ]` also prints `true`:

```
if [ -z ]; then echo "true"; else  echo "false"; fi
```

In the above code, why does the `[ -n ]` test assume the string value that is not passed at all, as not null?

The code below prints `false`. This is expected since the passed string value is null and of zero length.

```bash
if [ -n "" ]; then echo "true"; else  echo "false"; fi
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[`*x*`]` is equivalent to `[ -n`*x*`]` even if *x* starts with `-` provided there is no operand.

```
$ [ -o ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -eq ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -n -o ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -n -eq ] ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Note that historically, `[ -t ]` was testing whether stdout was a terminal (short for `[ -t 1 ]`) and some shells are still doing it (in the case of `ksh93` only when that `-t` is literal), so it's better to use `[ -n "$var" ]` than `[ "$var" ]`. Though that would still fail in some old `test` implementations for values of `$var` like `=`, in which case `[ "" != "$var" ]` or `[ "x$var" != x ]` or `case $x in "")...` may be better.

Comment: Interesting choice of `-o` here. In some shells like `bash`, `-o` is both a unary (test if an option is set) and binary (or) operator, so things like `[ ! -o monitor ]` are ambiguous. Is it testing that the `monitor` option is not set, or that either `!` or `monitor` are non-empty strings? POSIX rules decide: the latter (that's different with `[[ ! -o monitor ]]`).

Answer (score 32):

#### `[ -n ]` does not use the `-n` test.

The `-n` in `[ -n ]` is not a test at all. When there is only one argument between `[` and `]`, that argument is a string that is tested to see if it is empty. **Even when that string has a leading `-`,  it is still interpreted as an operand, not a test.** Since the string `-n` is not empty--it contains two characters, `-` and `n`, *not* zero characters--`[ -n ]` evaluates to true.

As [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400890/11938), where *`string`* is a single argument, the test performed on *`string`* in `[ string ]` is the same as the test performed on it by `[ -n string ]`. When *`string`* happens to be `-n`, nothing special happens. The `-n` in `[ -n ]` and the second `-n` in `[ -n -n ]` are simply strings being tested for emptiness.

When there is only one argument between `[` and `]`, that argument is always a string to be tested for nonemptiness, even if it happens to be named the same as a test. Similarly, when there are two arguments between `[` and `]` and the first of them is `-n`, the second one is always a string to be tested for nonemptiness, even if it happens to be named the same as a test. This is simply because the syntax for `[` insists that a single argument between `[` and `]` or after `-n` is a string operand.

**For the same reason that `[ -n ]` doesn't use the `-n` test, `[ -z ]` doesn't use the `-z` test.**

---

You can learn more about `[` in `bash` by examining the help for it. Notice that is a [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```

Thus you can run `help [` to get help on it:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

For more information, including what tests are supported and how they work, you will have to see the help on `test`. When you run the command `help test`, you'll get a detailed list. Rather than reproduce it all, here's the part about string operators:

```
      -z STRING      True if string is empty.

      -n STRING
         STRING      True if string is not empty.

      STRING1 = STRING2
                     True if the strings are equal.
      STRING1 != STRING2
                     True if the strings are not equal.
      STRING1 < STRING2
                     True if STRING1 sorts before STRING2 lexicographically.
      STRING1 > STRING2
                     True if STRING1 sorts after STRING2 lexicographically.
```

Notice that `-n STRING` and just `STRING` do the same thing: they test if the string `STRING` is not empty.

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: Maybe also mention that this has implication for non-quoted variables that are unset, like  this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25831047/

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think it may be better in a separate answer. Variables that are unset, or set but empty, or contain only `IFS` whitespace, will do that; variables that contain multiple words instead of zero produce another effect and may cause a completely different test to be run. Strings that appear literally with the intent of being operands will only work properly if they contain no spaces or tabs or if they are quoted. The answer would become much longer and more complicated if I covered this topic in an accessible way. If you decide to post answer, feel free to @ me here about it!

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, your answer is more complete and detailed although  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's  response answered my question.

Comment: I think you're missing the reason it is and has to be this way: if not, `[ "$var" ]` would never be usable as a test because`$var` might expand to `-n`.

Comment: Your answer also explains [`test -n`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141024/306023). Cheers!

Comment: Re: "When there is only one argument between [ and ], that argument is a string that is tested to see if it is empty." Then what's the difference between `[ "$x" ]` and `[ -n "$x" ]`? In my case they seem to behave identically; for `x=""` both return 1, and for `x="x"` both return 0.

Answer (score 14):

`[ -n ]` is true because the `[` command (aka the `test` command) acts upon the **number** of arguments it is given. If it is given only a single argument, the result is "true" if the argument is a non-empty string. "-n" is a string with 2 characters, not empty, therefore "true".