# Why does -n with unquoted variable containing empty string return true?

Tags: bash, variable, quoting, test

From `man bash`:

```
-n string
    True if the length of string is non‐zero.
```

Examples:

```
# expected
$ var=""; [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
1

# unexpected?
$ var=""; [ -n $var ]; echo $?
0
```

Here we see that `-n` with unquoted variable containing empty string returns true. Why?

Why is `$var` required to be quoted here?

Comment: Because  $ [ -n ]; echo $?
0

Comment: @stevea, that doesn't explain much. Why would `[ -n ]` be relevant when they clearly had `[ -n $var ]`? Why would `[ -n ]` be true? What does it even _mean_?

Comment: IOW -n with no argument returns true.  This is not well documented.   Your $var and "$var" evaluate to no-argument before /usr/bin/test is called.

Comment: @stevea, sigh... Claims like that about documentation would be much easier to accept if they came with some grounds, e.g. if you showed the piece of documentation you were reading, that didn't properly describe the behavior. See e.g. [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400895/170373) under [Why isn't [ -n ] false like [ -n "" ]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400889/170373) (The Q I linked there).

Comment: @stevea, also, `"$var"` will only ever result in one argument (or word/field, howevery you like), never none (nor more than one)

Comment: Sigh, do you need a pointer to the man pages ?   "man bash" states only "-n string
True if the length of string is non-zero.". It does NOT state behavior when the 'string' argument is zero-length, is a non-string, or is absent; therefore the documentation is clearly defective.

Comment: @ikkachu states: <<also, "$var" will only ever result in one argument (or word/field, howevery you like), never none (nor more than one) –  ilkkachu>>, but this is blatantly false.  Try "${!B@}" . Bash expansion is complex, with many exceptions, and marginally documented, leading to Ikkachu's understandable error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The $ sign introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

In your second case (`$var` unquoted) since `$var` is empty, it will expand to nothing. Just as if you had not specified any operand to the test.

In your first case, (`$var` double quoted) `$var` will still expand to nothing but within the double quotes, this incidentally providing the empty string `""` as operand to the test.

---

Update following [additional question from OP in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765702/why-does-n-with-unquoted-variable-containing-empty-string-return-true#comment1460147_765710) :

> why doesn't -n with no operand lead to, for example, "error: -n
> requires an operand"?

To which I had initially answered that, according to [the manual](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html), test

> Exits with a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false)

With false including the case where *"an invalid argument is given"*.

Some [comment from illkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765702/why-does-n-with-unquoted-variable-containing-empty-string-return-true/765710?noredirect=1#comment1460178_765710) provides a deeper insight :

> A few test implementations (including Bash's) actually do return a
> distinct falsy status for an error, i.e. 0 for true, 1 for false and 2
> for error

However :

> It's just that both 1 and 2 are falsy as far as shell conditionals are
> concerned

Comment: Any ideas / knowledge why doesn't `-n` with no operand lead to, for example, "error: -n requires an operand"? Does this question deserve to be posted as a new question?

Comment: @pmor : For reasons of coherence with bash *test* command I presume : See https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html in particular : *"Exit Status: Returns success if EXPR evaluates to true; fails if EXPR evaluates to false **or an invalid argument is given**."*

Comment: @pmor : In my above comment, I mean test gets a binary exit status (true exclusive-or false) not a ternary which could include some value that could be interpreted as sort of syntax error.

Comment: @MC68020, A few `test` implementations (including Bash's) actually do return a distinct falsy status for an error, i.e. 0 for true, 1 for false and 2 for error. It's just that both 1 and 2 are falsy as far as shell conditionals are concerned, so one often doesn't get to see the difference. It'd need explicitly looking at the value of `$?`. Not that there's any invalid arguments here in this case (and anyway, `[ -n ]` is true), but you could try e.g. `[ x x ]` or similar. e.g. `bash -c '[ x x ]; echo $?'` prints `2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ilkkachu (since I learnt something :-) ) for that deeper insight. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hence, "no argument" is not an "invalid argument". What's the rationale for `[ -n ]` to return 0 instead of non-zero? In other words: why the string is non-empty if there is no string? See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth .