Why does `if [ -d $EMPTY_VAR ]` return true?
I have written a Bash script which doesn't behave quite as I expected.
It contains the following lines of code.
TARGET_FOLDER=$1
echo "TARGET_FOLDER: $TARGET_FOLDER"
if [ ! -d $TARGET_FOLDER ]; then
    echo "target $TARGET_FOLDER is not a directory or does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

When this script is run with no arguments, TARGET_FOLDER is an empty string.
However, the test if [ ! -d $TARGET_FOLDER ] still returns true, and the echo statement does not run.
Why is this? Is this the expected behaviour? How can a directory with no name exist?

If you code in bash, use [[ ]] instead of [ ].

Test -n gives unexpected result

Why isn't [ -n ] false like [ -n ""]? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400889/170373

because $var for an empty variable expands to nothing, so [ -d $var ] turns into [ -d ], which tests if -d is an empty string or not

And with var='f -o -v Z[$(reboot)]', with a shell such as bash and with the default value of IFS would reboot. Variable expansions must be quoted in list contexts with any command, but [ aka test is one of those where it's critical to do so. Korn-style [[ ... ]] construct helps if you forget the quotes but comes with issues of its own. [ is standard and fine if used properly (with that quoting and not using the deprecated -a/-o binary operators)
