# what does the -z flag mean here

Tags: shell-script, test

What does the `-z` flag mean in the code below:

```
if [ -z $TEST_PARAM ]; then
```

And is there a list of such flags?

For a flag like `ls -l`, I know where to find it, but for a single flag, I didn't get any website describes it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-z STRING` [means](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test):

> the length of STRING is zero

You can see a list of all of these with [`man test`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test).

`[` is an alias for the `test` command,  although usually implemented by your shell in practice. You probably have a `/bin/[`, though. All of these `-X` tests are options to `test`.

Answer (score 2):

`[` is another name for the `test` utility. The only difference between them is that `[` expects an extra `]` parameter at the end. Most systems have a `[` man page with the same content as the `test` man page.

Most shells have `[` and `test` built in, so the exact capabilities described in the man page may differ slightly from those actually available in the shell. `-z` is a standard feature available in all implementations though. Look for the description of the `test` builtin or the section on conditional expressions to find operators like `-z`.

The command `[ -z $TEST_PARAM ]` should actually be `[ -z "$TEST_PARAM" ]`, because variable expansions outside double quotes do far more than expand variables. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more details. Without quotes, the value of `TEST_PARAM` is split into words which are expanded as glob patterns. In contrast, `"$TEST_PARAM"` expands to the value of the `TEST_PARAM` variable. If the value of `TEST_PARAM` is empty, then `$TEST_PARAM` is expanded into a list of zero words, so the command that is executed is `[ -z ]`. With only a single word to express the conditional expression, the conditional is true if this word is non-empty. Here `-z` is not an operator but some non-empty string.

See also [using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)

Answer (score 1):

It means "if the parameter doesn't exist, do the following".

You can see this with:

```
$ ABC='1'                                                                                     
$ 
$ if [ -z $ABC ]; then echo "ABC"; # Nothing
fi;                                                          
$
$ if [ -z $XYZ ]; then echo "yes"; # echo "Yes"
fi;                                                         
yes
$
```

One example of where I use this, is in my `.bashrc` file to invoke `tmux`, but not recursively, as in:

```
[ -z $TMUX ] && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```