# how to determine through code if command needs root elevation?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, acl

how to determine (though code .. or ACL) if a command would need needs root elevation i.e sun as sudo ? some commands need sudo .. some execute without sudo .. Is there a method to determine if sudo is needed ? any hints ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158488/386242 may be of use, even potentially duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat` to examine the command's owner and execute permissions.

However most of the time the reason you need `sudo` is not for how to invoke the command, but for the command's side effects: a couple of examples.

- use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab, but `sudo crontab -e` to edit root's crontab
- `chmod` to change permissions on your files, `sudo chmod` to change permissions on any file

Comment: Glenn - thanks but regrettably above doesn't work e.g getfacl /usr/bin/apt-get and getfacl /usr/bin/python3 both yield identical owner i.e root and identical permissions for owner , root and group .. where as apt needs sudo to run  .. I am looking for a method where need for sudo can be determined through a code or CLI

Comment: That was exactly my point: you don't need root to run it, but you need root for the side effects. And you can't get that programmatically, you need to _understand_ what the command _does_.