# How to use negation of a command in a while loop with grep in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, test

Is there any way to use while loop and grep all together?
See my example:

```
while  [[  !(grep -R -h "${text}" ${path}) ]];
do
    ...
done
```

It says:

```
./test_script.sh: line 1: conditional binary operator expected
./test_script.sh: line 1: expected `)'
./test_script.sh: line 1: syntax error near `-R'
./test_script.sh: line 1: `while  [[  !(grep -R -h "${text}" ${path}) ]];'
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ? Any expected output.

Comment: From this to work ... When grep does not find a specific text wait for another script to try complete its task to add this text and repeat every 10 seconds till its done and text is present...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't put commands inside square brackets. 
   To loop while `grep` succeeds (i.e., until it fails), just do

   ```
   while grep ...
   do
       ︙
   done
   ```
2. To loop while `grep` fails (i.e., until it succeeds), do

   ```
   while ! grep ...
   do
       ︙
   done
   ```

   with whitespace (i.e., one or more spaces and/or tabs)
   between the `!` and the command.
3. You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$path"`)
   unless you have a good reason not to,
   and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
   By contrast, while braces can be important,
   [they’re not as important as quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525),
   so `"$text"` and `"$path"` are good enough
   (you don't need to use `"${text}"` and `"${path}"`, in this context).

   … unless `path` might be set to a *list* of filenames, in which case, see
   [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells 
   — But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350)
4. You don't need the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `while` line
   (unless you put the `do` after it). 
   In other words, the `while` line and the `do` must be separated
   by a semicolon ***and/or*** one or more newlines.