# what does :g mean in this sed action?

Tags: sed

I know people use `:` instead of `/` when they are dealing with paths, but  what does `:g` do in the following `sed` action?

Why is path1 between quotation mark? Can anyone explain the action of this code?

```
sed -i -e s:INPUT_REPLACE:"${path1}":g ${path2}
```

Comment: Note (1) if the `s:INPUT_REPLACE:"${path1}":g` syntax looks weird to you, and you want an alternative, you can use `"s:INPUT_REPLACE:${path1}:g"` instead (moving the quotes from the inside to the beginning and the end), and (2) you should probably put `"$path2"` into quotes, too. (You can leave the braces in; e.g., `"${path2}"`, but they are unnecessary in this context. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216) for more information)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The colons `:` are delimiters for the pattern (left) and substitution (right).  `g` tells sed to "globally" substitute (change everything that matches the pattern on each line, rather than only the first on a given line).

Three colons are used, because you need three delimiters.  So `:g` is really two things: the last delimiter and the modifier "g".

The quotation mark is used in case this part of the expression **`"${path1}"`** contains some character (when the variable is substituted) that would make an error in the command.  For instance, if it contained a space or tab, that would break the substitution parameter passed by the shell to `sed` into two parts (an error).

So... this command

```
sed -i -e s:INPUT_REPLACE:"${path1}":g ${path2}
```

tells `sed` to read/write the same file (the `-i` option).  The file is `${path2}`.  It looks for lines containing `"INPUT_REPLACE"`, and replaces that string on each line with whatever is in the variable `${path1}`.  It does that for each occurrence of `"INPUT_REPLACE"` on each line.

By the way: if "${path1}" contains "INPUT_REPLACE" (or the substitution makes an occurrence), `sed` will **not** redo things and substitute again.  It only does this on the initial matches.

The `-i` option is not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), but is available with [Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) and [BSDs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3).