# How to use as argument the characters + , - , x , / in a script

Tags: bash, scripting, arguments

I am trying to write a script I will call calc.sh that does basic calculations using the arguments for the script ( $1, $2 and $3). For instance I'd like to get  2 as result for 
./calc.sh 10 / 5

My start goes as this:

```
if [ $2 -eq "+" ] ; then res=`expr $1 + $3` ; echo "$res" ; fi
```

But it won't work, I  get something like : Line 2 : [ +: an integer expression was expected

NOw That I used == to make the comparison is working fine for all the operations except the division /. The code now is:

```
if [ $2 == "+" ] ; then res=`expr $1 + $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "-" ] ; then res=`expr $1 - $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "x" ] ; then res=`expr $1 \* $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "/" ] ; then res=`expr $1 \/ $3` ;
else res=`Operación no válida` ;
fi ; echo "$res"
```

But if I try `./calc.sh 10 / 5`  , I will get:  "line 4:  10 / 5 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (the error element is "\ 5 ")... Alas as I am typing I'm realising it should be  $1 / $3 ...
:)

Comment: `man test` ... `-eq` is for numbers, for strings you want `=`.

Comment: Thank you! The == works, but when I use the "/" as argument it's not working. I'll try $(( $1 / $3 )) instead of expr $1 \\ $3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `bash`shell, you can try:

```
if [ $2 == "+" ] ;then
 res=$(($1 + $3))
 echo $res 
fi
```

**Edit**

Change the next line (note the substitution of `'` by `"`):

```
else res=`Operación no válida` ;
```

To:

```
else res="Operación no válida" ;
```

**Edit 2**

Instead of using so many `if else` statements, you can use a case statement:

```
case $2 in
+)
  res=`expr $1 + $3`
  ;;
-)
  res=`expr $1 - $3`
  ;;
/)
  res=`expr $1 \/ $3`
  ;;
x)
  res=`expr $1 \* $3`
  ;;
*)
  res="Operación inválida"
  ;;
esac

echo "$res"
```

Comment: Thank yo, I tried with == and is working fine except for the division symbol. if [ $2 == "+" ] ; then res=`expr $1 + $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "-" ] ; then res=`expr $1 - $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "x" ] ; then res=`expr $1 \* $3` ;
elif [ $2 == "/" ] ; then res=`expr $1 \\ $3` ;
else res=`Operación no válida` ;
fi ; echo "$res"

Comment: Division is `/`, so replace `res=expr $1 \\ $3` with `res=$(expr $1 / $3)`

Comment: The final code I used worked pretty well (see in the edited question), except for the case when I don't use one of the described operators (for instance something like./calc.sh 3 r 4)  I won't get the error message from the `else echo "operación inválida"`. But the question was pretty much answered. Should I do something now to signal this?

Comment: @LorenaR I updated my answer to address the problem with `else echo "operación inválida"`. Also, you can select the correct answer by clicking the "tick" below the two arrows

Answer (score 1):

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=" " # join arguments with a space character
echo "$* = $(( $* ))"
```

With `+` it is easy:

```
./calc.sh 10 + 2
10 + 2 = 12
```

But asterisk has to be escaped

```
./calc.sh 10 \* 2
10 * 2 = 20
```

or

```
./calc.sh 10 "*" 2
10 * 2 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexP has already pointed out, you are doing arithmetic instead of a string comparison.

I would also strongly suggest that you use **[double brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)** `[[]]` instead of single ones.

Your code can then be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $2 == "+" ]]; then
    echo $(($1+$3))
elif [[ $2 == "/" ]]; then
    echo $(($1/$3))
fi
```

Execution examples:

```
./math.sh 2 + 7
9
./math.sh 7 / 2
3
```

Comment: note than you can use `=` instead of `==` as those are synonyms when using double brackets

Comment: Yeah, but I really prefer not to. In every other language, `=` is an assignment operator, and I like to keep it that way!

Comment: = vs == is one of the methods some languages have used to distinguish between assignment and equality. There are several others like `:=` vs `=` (almost as common), `<-` vs `=`... See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Assignment_versus_equality. In any case the `[` command and the `[[..]]` construct have no assignment operator.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. Every other language **I have ever used** use `=` as an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

None of `+`, `-`, `x` or `/` are special to the shell or the `[` command. Your problem here is that:

- `-eq` is for numeric comparison. Use `=` instead of string comparison
- you forgot to quote your variables
- `==` is not a standard `sh` `[` operator

So:

```
if [ "$2" = + ]; then
  res=`expr "$1" + "$2"`
fi
```

Or use a `case` construct:

```
case $2 in
  + | - | /) res=`expr "$1" "$2" "$3"`;;
          x) res=`expr "$1" "*" "$3"`;;
          *) echo >&2 invalid; exit 1;;
esac
```

Note that you'd only use `expr` if you had to deal with ancient systems. Modern standard `sh` implementations have arithmetic expansions built-in via the `$((...))` operator and a better form of command substitution with `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't know about the `expr`. From now on I will use the `$((...))` operator.