# If condition works for first time but not for the second time

Tags: bash, test, for

I have defined the below for and if condition in a function. For the first time it runs well. Second time it doesn't gets executed after the for loop, it just writes the echo statement. Why does it behave like this?

```
for outputFile in $outputFiles
    do
            echo"Output file is $outputFile"

        if [ $outputFile == sampple*.pdf ]; then
            FromFile=$OutputFilePath
            transferFiles
         fi
done
```

Comment: It doesn't get executed after the first run is coz in the first run, you've transferred all relevant pdf files over, so next time on there aren't any there. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

To do a test on a string against a file globbing pattern, use `case`:

```
case "$outputFile" in
    sampple*.pdf)
        FromFile="$OutputFilePath"
        transferFiles ;;
esac
```

To do a test on a string against a regular expression in `bash` or `ksh93`:

```
if [[ "$outputFile" =~ ^sampple.*\.pdf$ ]]; then
    FromFile="$OutputFilePath"
    transferFiles
fi
```

Note the use of `[[ ... ]]` and `=~` rather than `[ ... ]` and `==` here.

The `[ ... ]` construct does not generally support the `==` operator for comparing strings.

With `[[ ... ]]` and `==`, the right-hand side is taken as a file globbing pattern. So the following should work (in `bash` or `ksh93`) as well:

```
if [[ "$outputFile" == sampple*.pdf ]]; then
   # as before
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)
But i have used [...] this in some other functions, there it works fine. I am facing this issue only for a particular function in the script. why does this happen?

Comment: We can't tell without seeing the values it loops over. Can you [edit] your question to include the output from `bash -x` on your script?

Comment: @user226759 It's hard to debug a "it doesn't work"-question blindfolded. Please edit your question with the relevant info included. This includes the values that `$outputFile` may take as well as any error messages. Also note that if your `outputFiles` variable contains spaces, the shell will split the variable on _all_ of these and set `$outputFile` to each individual bit in turn.

Comment: @user226759 `[` works with some operators, but not with pattern matching because you need to quote the pattern. See [Single or double brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash/32227#32227).