# How was I able to access the 14th positional parameter using $14 in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I was reading about positional parameters in Unix and then I found this info:

> The shell allows a command line to contain at least 128 arguments;
> however, a shell program is restricted to referencing only nine
> positional parameters, $1 through $9, at a given time. You can work
> around this restriction by using the shift command.

So I created a simple shell script called `file` like the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $14
```

then ran it like the following :

```
./file 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

and I got 14!

So how is that possible if the shell doesn't allow more than 10 parameters (from $0 to $9) without using `shift` command?

Comment: ... try `./file a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o`

Comment: Ok , it gave me "a4" this is because it reads it as $1 then number 4 , aha now I get it I also replaced the number 14 in my example and it give the same result , now everything is clear i was using bad example , thanks a lot mate @steeldriver

Comment: Most modern shells allow you to reference higher-numbered parameters with `${ }` (try `echo "${14}"`).

Comment: ... indeed - see also [When to quote a parameter expansion, and enclose parameter name in braces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421737/when-to-quote-a-parameter-expansion-and-enclose-parameter-name-in-braces)

Comment: Bash behaviour is documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's standard behavior. Only very old pre-POSIX shells would choke on `${14}` (or `${014}`). The OP is reading outdated documentation.

Comment: _"The shell allows a command line to contain at least 128 arguments;"_ it does say "at least", but that's probably an outdated limitation too. At least on Linux, some 100000 args still work, e.g. `dash -c 'echo ${100000}' - {1..99999} xxx` gives `xxx`. I wouldn't say it works _fine_ with Bash though, on Bash 4.4. it takes ages to start when given so many args.

Comment: Using a value equals to the variable name when testing something is always a bad idea

Comment: @steeldriver It's not often that I read a fragment of shell script and laugh out loud :-)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When you run

```
echo $14
```

what happens is that bash interprets the argument `$14` as `$1` and `4` separately. It then expands `$1` (which in this case is equal to "1"), then appends the string `4` to it, which results in "14". Although that was the result you were expecting, it's actually a side effect from Bash's actual behaviour. Like @steeldriver mentioned in comments, running your script like this instead :

```
./file a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
```

and then calling `echo $14` won't output "n" but "a4".

Note that wrapping the variable in double-quotes :

```
echo "$14"
```

will still not expand the variable correctly in Bash. The standard method is to use curly braces around the variable name :

```
echo ${14}
```

For more information, see the official documentation for [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in Bash. It can do a lot more cool things too, like

```
${14^^*}
```

to capitalize argument no.14. Give it a read! :)

Comment: Note that that "bug" (unfortunately mandated by POSIX) where `$14` is `${1}4` instead of `${14}` was fixed in csh, ash, tcsh, rc, es, akanga and zsh (when not in sh/ksh emulation), though broken again in some ash derivatives for POSIX compliance.

Comment: Just wrapping the variabled in double quotes does not work: `bash -c 'echo "$14"' - WTF` => `WTF4`.

Comment: If that worked for you, it's because you had used `dash` (Debian's `/bin/sh`) where simply `echo $14` would've worked too: `dash -c 'echo $14' - a b c d e f g h i j k l m n` => `n`.

Comment: @user414777 Indeed. I used bash but I didn't test it properly. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user414777, fwiw, that seems to be fixed in newer versions of Dash

Comment: @ilkkachu, *fixed* or *broken* depending on how you want to look at it. As per my first comment here, it used to be fine but was *broken* (IMO) in newer versions for POSIX compliance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, well. As far as I understand, Dash is meant to implement the POSIX shell language as it is, instead of creating a new but actually sane language. So in that context, behaviour that's both noncompliant and different from almost all other POSIX-like shells seems unquestionably a bug.