# Why is this number matched with this regex?

Tags: regular-expression

The regex is `-?([0-9]|([1-9][0-9]))`.

The number is `-2231` and it's being matched. From my understanding, it should be a single digit or double digits. 
Why is this number matched with this regex?

Comment: It has 4 matches: [See the explanation online](https://regex101.com/r/x0HolZ/1)[.](http://roboter-basteln.de/)

Comment: A match can be found in the string, but it doesn't match the whole string.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller:  The original version of this question contained a regular expression *in (ordinary, single) quotes*, and you ***added*** back ticks without removing the quotes.  That makes it look like the single quotes are part of the regex that the OP is asking about, which makes the question very confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @G-man. I’m accustomed to seeing regexes in quotes to protect them from shell interpretation. The number wouldn’t have matched a regex that required quote marks, but it’s better to be clear about things, so thank you for the improvement!

Comment: @Jeff Schaller:  Yeah, it occurred to me later that, if I had seen the regex in quotes in the context of a command line, it would have been perfectly clear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The regular expression is not anchored, so it's free to match the first 1 or two numbers and "succeed", leaving the trailing numbers (successfully) unmatched.

If you require 1 or 2 digit numbers, anchor the regex:

```
'^-?([0-9]|([1-9][0-9]))$'
```

Some examples:

```
$ seq -100 -99 | grep -E '^-?([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
-99

$ seq 99 100 | grep -E '^-?([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
99

$ seq -9 9  | grep -E '^-?([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
-9
-8
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

$ seq -2231 -100 | grep -E '^-?([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
(empty)
```

Comment: See also the `-x` `grep` option to anchor the regexp at start and end.

Comment: Note that $ anchors to end of line. If you want to anchor to the end of the "word", use \b (if that it supported by your regex flavor).

Answer (score 14):

Most programs that use regex patterns actually implement a *search* of the pattern, instead of a full-string *match*. Python has distinct [`search()` and `match()`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/170373) methods where `search()` matches anywhere in the string, and `match()` only at the beginning. `grep` has the `-x` option to demand a match against the whole string; by default it matches anywhere in the string. Others, like `sed`, `awk` and Perl will happily look for the pattern anywhere in the string. Use the `^` and `$` modifiers ("anchors") to force the pattern to the start or end of the string (respectively).

So, the ERE pattern you want is probably this:

```
^-?[1-9]?[0-9]$
```

Comment: See also `expr` that anchors at the start but not at the end (uses BREs though, not those EREs).

Comment: I like this answer because it explains that regular expressions can only be evaluated in the context in which they're used.  Sometimes the regex must match the entire string, other times it must only be found somewhere within another string.  The OP's question can't be answered without understand what program or function the regex is used within.

Comment: i just put the number in vi editor