# if condition throws error

Tags: bash

In bash coding, line3 is a path taken from xyz/symlinks_paths.txt.

```
while read -r line3
do
    if [[ $(ls -lh $line3 | grep zzz.exe | grep '[8-9][0-9][0-9][MG]') -ne 0 ]] 
    then 
        echo $line3 >> xyz/size_list.txt
        exit 1
    fi
done < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt
```

The script throws me the following error. (h.sh is the script name.)

```
h.sh: line 20: [[: -r--r--r-- 1 syncmgr GX 838M Dec  1 21:55 zzz.txt: syntax error in expression (error token is "r--r-- 1 syncmgr GX 838M Dec  1 21:55 zzz.txt")
```

Comment: Does your `line3` by any chance come from having done an `ls` on a directory? Is the overall purpose to get files that are larger than 800M? If so, `find dir -type f -size +800M` does that (in `dir`). No need to parse `ls` or call `grep` or loop, or explicitly test variables or anything.

Comment: BTW, why the `exit 1`?  do you only want to print the name of the **first** file in `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`  that's greater than 800MB?

Comment: no @cas, i want to name all the files more than 800M. What should i do for that? Thats what i wonder why am i getting only 1 result. Can you help me on bypassing the loop, i dont have an else condition, so what should i write?

Comment: uhhhh....don't `exit 1` inside the loop.  i.e. you're telling the script to exit after printing the first match.  if you don't want it to do that, then don't tell it to.   BTW, you don't need an `else` condition.  Another way of looking at that is "the default `else` condition is to do nothing".

Comment: that means i will remove the `exit 1` part and i dont want to write the else part. Just `if [ true ] then ... fi` ? will `if` work without `else`? i think yes. I will experiment. Thanks. :)

Comment: yep. i'll edit my answer to show it.

Comment: @Kusalananda using `find` was my first thought too - but the files to examine are listed in a file called `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`.    Admittedly, if the only thing that file is used for is this while loop then the OP could just use `find` as you suggest.   Also, I suspect that the list is a list of symlinks, not regular files, so use `-type l` rather than `-type f`.

Comment: @cas I was thinking in the lines of bypassing that text file altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to parse the output of `ls`.  This is **always** a bad idea.  See [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) for an explanation of why that is the case.

If you want the size of a file, then use `stat`.  e.g.

```
minsize=$(( 800 * 1024 * 1024 ))

# alternatively, if you have `numfmt` from GNU coreutils, delete the line above
# and uncomment the following line:
#minsize=$(echo 800M | numfmt --from=iec)

while read -r line3 ; do
  if [ "$(stat -L --printf '%s' "$line3")" -gt "$minsize" ]; then
    echo "$line3" >>  xyz/size_list.txt
  fi
done < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt
```

Note: I've used `stat`'s `-L` (aka `--dereference`) option above because the input filename implies that the filenames listed in it might be symbolic links.  Without `-L`, `stat` won't follow a symlink, it would print the size of the symlink itself.

---

If you want the file size printed to the output file along with the filename, then the `while` loop would be more like the following:

```
while read -r line3 ; do
  fsize=$(stat -L --printf '%s' "$line3")

  if [ "$fsize" -gt "$minsize" ]; then
    fsize=$(echo "$fsize" | numfmt --to=iec)
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$fsize" "$line3" >>  xyz/size_list.txt
  fi
done < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt
```

Comment: i want size of file greater than 800MB.

Comment: that's easy. see updated answer.

Comment: no, i want in human readable format, so thta it appears in M and G. and i want to filter size like that. thats why i used  `grep '[8-9][0-9][0-9][MG]'`

Comment: that's also why what you tried didn't work.   You're not even outputting the file size to your size_list.txt so why do you even care how it is compared?  If you really want to specify the size in human-readable format, you can use `numfmt` to convert to a size in bytes.

Comment: you could use `du -h ${line3} | cut -f1` to get the human-readable size easily, if there's some particular reason `stat` is undesirable.

Comment: @quixotic what?  braces don't protect against spaces in filenames.  double-quoting does that.  braces are used to clearly distinguish a variable name from other text that the shell would otherwise interpret as being part of the variable name.  e.g. `echo $foobar` is not the same as `echo ${foo}bar` (the former prints out variable `$foobar`.  the latter prints variable `$foo` followed by literal text `bar`.

Comment: @quixotic BTW sh can't easily do comparisons with human-readable formats like that.  The shell's comparison operators like `-gt`, `-ge`, `-lt`, `-le` etc work on numbers only, specifically integers.  To do such comparisons, you have to convert the human-readable numbers to integers.

Comment: @cas, word splitting and filename expansion [aren't performed inside `[[ .. ]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005d_005d), so the double-quotes wouldn't really do anything. Actually, I think `[[ x -ne y ]]` takes `x` and `y` as arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @quixotic, no, they don't.

Comment: @quixotic, all that the braces do in parameter expansion is allow you to stick word characters after the variable name: `$foobar` vs `${foo}bar`. And of course open the door for the expansions that manipulate the value.

Comment: @ilkkachu true, i keep forgetting that about `[[`.  Probably because I only ever use `[[ .. ]]` when I want to do a regexp match without forking sed or grep.  TBH I find the fact that quoting isn't required in them a little bit squick-worthy...it feels "dirty" to not quote my variables (and not in a good way).

Comment: @ilkkachu btw, you're also right about "`[[ x -ne y ]]` takes x and y as arithmetic expressions" but "Don't parse ls" is better advice than "you're parsing ls wrong".

Comment: @quixotic: [${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `find` (and `xargs`),
but it won’t win any beauty contests.

Write a script called `check_files`:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" -size +800M –print
```

Then run

```
xargs -d '\n' < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt ./check_files
```

where

- You can move `< xyz/symlinks_paths.txt` redirection
  to the end of the command line,
  as in `xargs -d '\n' ./check_files < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`,
  or to the beginning, or anywhere else. 
  Or you can replace it with `-a xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`. 
  Any of these mean that `xargs` will read from `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`.
- You can replace `./check_files`
  with an absolute pathname to your `check_files` script.

`-d '\n'` means use newline as the delimiter
when reading `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`. 
You can probably leave this off
if your filenames don’t contain whitespace (space(s) or tab(s)),
quotes (remember that a single quote (`'`)
is the same character as an apostrophe)
or backslashes,
and you’re willing to wager a year’s salary that they never ever will.

This reads each line of the file
and makes it an argument to the `check_files` script,
which passes them to `find` **as *starting-point* arguments**. 
Many people know that you can run `find`
with multiple *starting-point* arguments; e.g.,

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3  search-expression
```

It’s not so well known that those arguments don’t have to be directories;
they can be files; e.g.,

```
find file1 file2 file3  search-expression
```

(or a mixture of directories and files). 
`find` will simply apply the *expression*
to each file named as a *starting-point*.

So this checks each file whose name is listed in `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt`
to see whether its size is 800M or more, and prints those that are.

If the filenames might refer to symbolic links
(as the `xyz/symlinks_paths.txt` name suggests)
and you want to look at the pointed-to files (which you surely do),
change `find` to `find -L`.

You don’t need to have a separate `check_files` script; you can do

```
xargs -d '\n' < paths.txt sh -c 'find "$@" -size +800c -print' sh
```

Again, change `find` to `find -L` if desired.

Comment: **<rant>** `xargs` was brain-damaged 40 years ago, when treated its input like the shell command line (words are separated by spaces, unless quoted or escaped), and it’s not much better now. I couldn’t figure out how to get it to treat each line of input as a separate argument to the program to be run, with multiple arguments per invocation, with other arguments following. `-I {}` seems to force `-L 1` (one line → one invocation), and `-I {} -L 999` ignores the `-I {}` and just appends arguments to the command line. **</rant>** What am I missing?

Comment: FYI you've written `file -L` twice when you obviously meant `find -L`.   also, re: *what are you missing with xargs?*  Nothing.  That's how `-I` works.   [freebsd's xargs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html) has a `-J` option that doesn't force `-L 1` or `-n 1`.  GNU's `xargs` hasn't copied it ("yet", I hope).

Comment: And the only thing good about using xargs here is that at least it's not a shell `while read` loop :-)

Comment: @cas: Thanks for catching the typo.  The first time, it was my cat walking over the keyboard, and the second time I copied&pasted the first one.    :-)    ⁠