# Implement a script in Solaris when usage in all filesys >90% & send a mail i dont know how to send mail from script

Tags: bash, shell-script, email

Script in Solaris when usage in all filesystem >90% & send a mail i don't know how to send mail from script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Outputs alert if filesystem is above 90%
{
        for fs in $(df -hk | awk '{print $6}' | sed '1 d'); do
                chk=$(df -hk ${fs} | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
                if [ ${chk} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
                        echo "$(hostname): Alert Fileystem ${fs} is above ${threshold}%."
                fi
        done
```

It's getting "unary operator expected".

Comment: You would need to have a mail client installed first. Something like `ssmtp`. It has simple configuration. After you've properly configured `ssmtp` you can parse output of `df` with `awk` and execute `sendmail -t `  with here-doc structure as input text. Unfortunately, I've no solaris box at hand to provide a complete answer on how to install `ssmtp` in the first place, so that's some research you'll have to do yourself probably, or wait for someone to expand on this comment as a proper answer

Comment: As Romeo says, you should put all your variables into quotes.  But also, the braces don’t really do you any good; you can say just `"$fs"`, `"$chk"` and `"$threshold"`; see [${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525)

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` command you should add double quotes around the variables. And check if those variables have something assigned to them:

```
 if [ "${chk}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
```

To send mail you can use your `echo` command on this way

```
echo "$(hostname): Alert Fileystem ${fs} is above ${threshold}%."|mail user@host
```

If you want one mail for all you can use something like:

```
>/tmp/output
for fs in $(df -hk | awk '{print $6}' | sed '1 d'); do
chk=$(df -hk ${fs} | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
if [ "${chk}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
  echo "$(hostname): Alert Fileystem ${fs} is above ${threshold}%." >>/tmp/output
fi
done
cat /tmp/output|mailx -s "Subject" username@host
```

EDIT1: And one more point, command `df -hk` is a bit nonsense, you want on the same time result in human readable format ('h') and to be in kilobytes ('k')

Comment: exactly worked fine as per your suggestions but there is an issue in the received mail...in from address it showed the server name but it didnt mention the filesystem name and for every filesystem it sent a seperate mail rather than a cumulative mail

Comment: and is there a way to mention the subject in the mail..the mail was received without any subject

Comment: @user338853, you can add this information in temporary file which you can send later

Comment: @user338853, add also subject support

Comment: i did those steps but got this error

Comment: The flags you gave are used only when sending mail.
Usage: mailx -eiIUdFntBNHvV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address
                -s SUBJECT -f FILE users

Comment: @user338853, correct. At the end you want to send mail, right? And there was one space missing (add it)

Comment: i can't thank you enough for the super fast responses...finally can you guide me how to run that in crontab for every 5hours

Comment: @user338853, if you are happy with the answer please consider to upvote and/or accept the answer. About run in `cron` please ask new question

Comment: sure will do...there are 38 filesys in the server and I am getting 38 mails under a single mail like a chained mail....is there a way around to recieve it as single mail?

Comment: @user338853, i forgot to add `done` operator in the script, please check my updated answer (to send only one mail)

Comment: i added done and executed but still the same result..mails are coming incrementally

Comment: Edit it again, sorry, some problem with inline editor :)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
threshold="1"
{
        >/tmp/output
        for fs in $(df -hk | awk '{print $6}' | sed '1 d'); do
                chk=$(df -hk ${fs} | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
                if [ "${chk}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
                        echo "$(hostname): Alert Fileystem ${fs} is above ${threshold}%." >>/tmp/output
                fi
        cat /tmp/output| mailx -s "Critical Space Alert" abc@xyz.com
        done
}

Comment: thats the exact one i am using..yet i am getting huge number of mails ;)

Comment: No, the `done`must be before mail command (after `fi`)

Comment: fabulous...kudos....your help is highly is appreciated and i'll upvote :)