# Rename file using grep and for

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to rename files with following extensions: .txt, .data, .conf to ".xml"

*hello.txt -> hello.xml*

To do so, file must also contain the following line: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

This is what I have:

```
for file in *
do
if [ $(grep -Rc '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' --include ".txt" --include ".data" --include "*.conf") = true ]
then
rename extension to: .xml
fi
done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You used the `-R` option to `grep`, so you need recursion, right? I. e., you need to affect matching files in directories below the current one?

Comment: The string `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ` must be in the first line of the file?

Comment: @Quasímodo Correct.

Comment: @PauloTomé Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.data" -o -name "*.conf" \) -exec sh -c '
    for file in "$@"; do
        if grep -qF "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" "$file"; then
            mv -- "$file" "${file%.*}.xml"
        fi
    done
' findshell {} +
```

I think `find` is more adequate in this context. It looks recursively for regular files with `.txt`, `.data` and `.conf` extensions and checks if the string you provided is present in each of them. If yes, then it will change the extension to `.xml` by a `mv` command.

If you are unsure whether the code will work as expected, you can add an `echo` before `mv` to see what it does.

I should also mention that that script does not depend on non-POSIX utilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to do it with `grep` and `for` then perhaps something like this?

```
grep -RlZ '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' --include "*.txt" --include "*.data" --include "*.conf" | 
  xargs -0 sh -c 'for f; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.xml"; done' sh
```

(remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it's doing the right thing).

- `grep -RlZ` outputs a null-delimited list of the names of files where matches are found
- `xargs -0` passes that null-separated list to `sh -c`
- `for f` loops over the filenames as positional parameters

or (if you are allowed to use `while` rather than `for`) you can skip the `xargs` and the additional shell scriptlet like

```
grep -RlZ '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' --include "*.txt" --include "*.data" --include "*.conf" | 
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.xml"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for file in *.{txt,conf}; do 
  [[ $(grep "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" "$file") ]] && \
  mv "$file" "${file%.*}.xml" || echo "$file" " does not match"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob extglob

string='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

for pathname in ./**/*.@(txt|data|conf); do
    if [[ -f $pathname ]] && grep -q -F "$string" "$pathname"; then
        mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%.*}.xml"
    fi
done
```

I start by setting a number of shell options that are not usually set in `bash` by default:

- `globstar` enables the `**` globbing pattern that matches into subdirectories recursively.
- `dotglob` makes globbing patterns match hidden names.
- `nullglob` makes a non-matching pattern disappear completely, instead of remaining unexpanded. This ensures that our loop later will not run at all if there is no match.
- `extglob` enable extended globbing patterns, for example `@(txt|data|conf)` which matches one of the strings inside the parenthesis.

We then loop over the candidate names and test each one for the given string.  If the string is found, the file is renamed by replacing the filename suffix after the last dot character by `xml`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `[[ ... ]]` is not a command, like `[ ... ]` is. It's shell grammar. The expansion therefore does not need to be quoted. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/why-does-parameter-expansion-with-spaces-without-quotes-work-inside-double-brack?noredirect=1&lq=1