# What's the difference between test command and individual conditional expression surrounded by [[]]?

Tags: zsh, quoting, test

I am learning the zsh in the conditional expressions part, and I found some unreasonable output.

For example:

```
$ mkdir emptyspace && cd emptyspace
$ var_assigned_with_emptystring=""

$ [[ -n $var_assigned_with_emptystring ]] && echo 'var_assigned_with_emptystring is a nonzero-len string!'
$ [[ -n "" ]] && echo '"" is a nonzero-len string!'

$ test -n $var_assigned_with_emptystring && echo 'var_assigned_with_emptystring is a nonzero-len string by test!'
var_assigned_with_emptystring is a nonzero-len string by test!
$ test -n "" && echo '"" is a nonzero-len string by test!' 

----------


$ [[ -z $var_assigned_with_emptystring ]] && echo 'var_assigned_with_emptystring is a zero-len string!'
var_assigned_with_emptystring is not an empty string!
$ [[ -z "" ]] && echo '"" is a zero-len string!'
"" is a zero-len string!

$ test -z $var_assigned_with_emptystring && echo 'var_assigned_with_emptystring is a zero-len string by test!'
var_assigned_with_emptystring is a zero-len string by test!
$ test -z "" && echo '"" is a zero-len string by test!'
"" is a zero-len string by test!
```

1. Why does the `test` with a `var_assigned_with_emptystring` always gives a true result no matter it is with `-n` or `-z` option? What's the difference between `test` command and individual conditional expression surrounded by `[[]]`?
2. What is the difference between `""` and `var_assigned_with_emptystring`? I think the parameter should have be expended(or evaluated) to a same value as `""` when it comes to process in the internal part of test function. But `test -n $var_assigned_with_emptystring` gives a different return status with `test -n ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly covered in [Why does parameter expansion with spaces without quotes work inside double brackets "[[" but not inside single brackets "["?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/why-does-parameter-expansion-with-spaces-without-quotes-work-inside-double-brack). In a nutshell, `[[ … ]]` is special syntax with different parsing rules, whereas `test` and `[` are ordinary commands.

In plain `sh` (including `ksh`, `bash`, etc.), `test -n $var` applies splitting and globbing to the value of `var` due to the lack of double quotes. This doesn't happen inside double brackets.

The `zsh` twist is that `zsh` mostly doesn't require double quotes around variable expansion. However, there is one difference between `$var` and `"$var"` in list contexts such as in a command line: if a word is empty and doesn't contain any quotes, `zsh` removes it. So when the value of `var` is empty, `test -n $var` is the command `test` with one argument `-n`, and `test` with a single non-empty argument is "true". But `test -n "$var"` is the command `test` with two arguments `-n` and an empty string, which applies the test `-n` to the empty string, which is "false".

Inside `[[ … ]]`, the empty-word removal doesn't happen, so `[[ -n $var ]]` and `[[ -n "$var" ]]` are equivalent.