# Convert to uppercase, except for escaped characters

Tags: bash, escape-characters

The methods I found break things further down the line by also affecting linebreaks.
For example...

```
$ message="First Line\nSecond Line"; 
$ echo "${message^^}"
FIRST LINE\NSECOND LINE
```

Is there an elegant way to convert a string to uppercase, but leaving escaped characters alone, to get the following output instead?

```
FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE
```

I could just do something convoluted like changing "\n" to 0001 or something along those lines, apply the conversion and then return 0001 to "\n". But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Is this for later inclusion as part of some other data, possibly in XML or JSON format? If so, a parser of that format may possibly have routines for turning strings into uppercase in the way you describe, as, for example, `ascii_upcase` in tho JSON parser `jq`, or the XPath function `upper-case()` for XML.

Comment: @Kusalananda For me this is only about text processing, but someone else stumbling across this question might have such a use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
echo "$message"  |  sed -e 's/^[[:lower:]]/\u&/' -e 's/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g' \
                                                 -e 's/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g'
```

- `-e 's/^[[:lower:]]/\u&/'` 
  If the first character in the string
  (or, more generally, the first character on a line)
  is a lower-case letter, capitalize it. 
  Because the first character on a line can’t be escaped. 
  Duh. 
  That’s a no-brainer.
- `-e 's/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g'` 
  Look at the line two characters at a time. 
  If a lower-case letter is preceded by something other than a backslash,
  leave the preceding character alone, and capitalize the lower-case letter.

  You might think that this would be enough to process the entire line. 
  Unfortunately, since it processes the line two characters at a time,
  it gets only every other letter:

  ```bsh
  $ echo "first line\nsecond line" | sed -e 's/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g'
  fIrSt LiNe\nSeCoNd LiNe
  ```

  so,
- `-e 's/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g'` 
  Do the exact same thing a second time. 
  This will pick up the letters that were skipped on the first pass.

---

**Alternative version:**

```
echo "$message" | sed -e 's/^[[:lower:]]/\u&/' \
                                  -e ': loop; s/\([^\]\)\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\u\2/g; t loop'
```

Basically the same as the first version,
but, instead of repeating the second **`s`** command,
it iterates it with a loop.

---

Unfortunately, this will not work correctly for double backslashes: 
`foo\\bar` will become `FOO\\bAR`, even though the `b` should be capitalized,
since the `\\` is an escaped backslash,
and so should not cause the `b` to be escaped.

Comment: No, the first character could be escaped, like when you want to insert a tab at the beginning, which would be "\t".

Comment: One of us is not understanding the other.  If the line begins with `\t`, then *the first character* is ``\``.  `t` is *the **second** character.*  If I’m misunderstanding you, please explain more clearly.

Comment: Semantics. If a line begins with "\t", then the first character is an escaped "t". But one can also say that "\" is the first character. Depends on how you look at it, I guess. It could also be an escaped "\" by having "\\t", so one gets "\t" instead of the tab character. Since these constructs are supposed to represent a single character (\t is tab), I treat them as single entities, which was the origin of the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
$ message="First Line\nSecond Line"
$ set -o extendedglob
$ print -r -- ${message//(#b)((\\?)|(?))/$match[2]$match[3]:u}
FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE
```

In `bash` (or any shell) and with the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can do the same with:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$message" | sed -E 's/(\\.)|(.)/\1\u\2/g'
FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE
```

Some potentially more efficient variants as they minimise the number of substitutions:

- `zsh`

  ```
  print -r -- ${message//(#b)((\\?)|([^\\]##))/$match[2]$match[3]:u}
  ```

  or

  ```
  print -r -- ${message//(#b)((\\?)#)([^\\]##)/$match[1]$match[3]:u}
  ```
- their GNU `sed` translations:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "$message" | sed -E 's/(\\.)|([^\\]+)/\1\U\2/g'
  ```

  or

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "$message" | sed -E 's/((\\.)*)([^\\]+)/\1\U\3/g'
  ```

Beware they convert `\Mx` (Meta-x, an escape sequence supported by `zsh`'s `print` for instance and that expands to the 0xf8 byte ('x' + 0x80)) to `\MX` (0xd8). They also convert `\x7a` to `\x7A` or `\u007a` to `\u007A` or `\Cx` to `\CX` but that shouldn't be a problem as those expand to the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be tempted to interpret the escape sequences into literal characters:

```bsh
message="First Line\nSecond Line"
declare -u Message                       # uppercase on assignment
printf -v Message -- "${message//%/%%}"  # assign
declare -p Message                       # inspect
```

result

```
declare -u msg="FIRST LINE
SECOND LINE"
```

Comment: Beware that with `message='\141'` for instance, you'd get `declare -u Message="A"` instead of `declare -u Message="a"`

Comment: Note that any ```\``` will ve doubled ```\\```.

Comment: Not giving `printf` a format causes the change of `%` that you want to avoid by duplicating every `%`. However, a `printf -v Message '%b' -- "${message}"` will interpret back-slashed characters exactly as `echo -e` without changing the `%`s.

Comment: Please read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700508/232326

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider evaluating the `\n` and other escape sequences at the point that the variable was defined. Here `$message` actually contains a newline.

```
message=$(printf '%b' 'First Line\nSecond Line')
echo "${message^^}"
```

Output

```
FIRST LINE
SECOND LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable can be iterated line by line. Then concatenate the output again.

bash:

```
$ message="First Line\nSecond Line";
$ message=$(echo -e ${message} |while read -r line; do echo -n "${line^^}\n" ; done) && message=${message%??}
$ echo ${message} 
FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE
```

Comment: See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123), [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: That will likely leave linefeeds alone, but the OP asked for all escaped characters to be left alone.

Comment: Backslash processing should be removed from the while read loop for sure. Just edited the answer.

Comment: (1) For starters, `${message}` should be `"$message"`.  See [`${variable_name}` doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525).  (2) You should explain your answer better — in particular (IMO) the `%??` part. (You don’t need to explain it *to me;* I figured it out.) … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) This is a classic example of providing a solution for the example while ignoring the larger question.  `foo\012bar` will turn into `FOO\nBAR`, `\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q` will turn into `\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\n\O\P\Q`, and any of `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\e`, `\f`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v`, and ``\\`` will cause problems.  Also, leading and trailing spaces, and multiple spaces. (4) Strictly speaking, the question didn’t say that you should clobber the original variable.  If you need a multi-step process, you should assign the intermediate value to a `temp` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```bash
~$ echo 'a\nb'
a\nb
~$ echo 'a\nb' | raku -pe 's:g/ <!after "\\"> (.) /{$0.uc}/;'
A\nB
~$ echo "a\\nb"
a\nb
~$ echo "a\\nb" | raku -pe 's:g/ <!after "\\"> (.) /{$0.uc}/;'
A\nB
```

Above uses a negative look-behind assertion, `<!after "\\">`, to select out all characters except those immediately after a `\` backslash. Selected characters are then uppercased with Raku's `.uc` routine.

Certainly it's safer to provide the regex with a custom `<-[ … ]>` ***negative*** character class, sparing backslashed characters like `\n` and `\t` from being uppercased. (FYI, custom *positive* character classes are written `<+[ … ]>` or more simply `<[ … ]>` in Raku).

Below, using Raku's "Q-lang" (quoting language) to feed the substitution operator a string. In all four examples below `\n` is returned (not uppercase `\N`). Note in the third example how `\n` is *operationally-interpreted* as a newline character, and this remains unchanged in the fourth example, telling us that `\n` still exists in that string (i.e. it has NOT been uppercased to `\N`):

```bash
~$ raku -e 'put Q<a\nb>'
a\nb
~$ raku -e 'put Q<a\nb>' | raku -pe 's:g/ <!after "\\"> (<-[nt]>) /{$0.uc}/;'
A\nB
~$ raku -e 'put Q:b<a\nb>'
a
b
~$ raku -e 'put Q:b<a\nb>' | raku -pe 's:g/ <!after "\\"> (<-[nt]>) /{$0.uc}/;'
A
B
```

NOTE, see: [*"Place an escape sign before every non-alphanumeric characters"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429694/place-an-escape-sign-before-every-non-alphanumeric-characters/72453516#72453516) for Raku answers to a related question on StackOverflow.

References:
https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Literals_and_metacharacters
https://raku.org