# Are there security consequences from not giving printf a format to use?

Tags: shell, security, printf

A well-formed `printf` usually has a format to use:

```bsh
$ var="Hello"
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
Hello
```

However, what could be the security implications of not providing a format?

```bsh
$ printf "$var"
Hello
```

As the variable expansion is quoted, there should not be any issues, are there?

Comment: `var='%'; printf "$var"`

Comment: @roaima I am failing to follow. What's the security issue generated by var='%'; printf "$var" ?

Comment: are you talking about the shell command `printf` or the C function `printf()`; 'cos the answer is different, depending.

Comment: Well ... I tagged the question with `shell`, so yes, it is the (usually a builtin) shell `printf`. Should I add some text to the question to clarify? Feel free to add as you see fit. thanks. @StephenHarris

Comment: Technically, it's incorrect to say that you're "not providing a format" when you run `printf "$var"`.  The first argument *is* the format.  What you're doing is providing an unpredictable/dynamic format string and no *arguments*.

Comment: "_What's the security issue generated by `var='%'; printf "$var"`?_" - the program outputs (arguably) unexpected errors. If the program is part of a security module then the error output might trigger unwanted consequences. I can't give a definitive answer to a conjectural question, though

Answer (score 31):

In:

```
printf "$var"
```

There are two problems:

- variable data passed as the format. Could be a problem if `$var` is under the control of an attacker
- option delimiter (`--`) missing, so `$var` could be taken as an option if it starts with `-`.

It would be a lot worse with:

```
printf $var
```

Where split+glob in most Bourne-like shells is performed upon `$var` expansion on top of that causing the sort of security vulnerabilities mentioned at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346).

Here that would be up to arbitrary command execution:

```
$ export var1='-va[1$(uname>&2)] x' var2='%d a[1$(uname>&2)]'
$ bash -c 'printf $var1'
Linux
$ ksh -c 'printf $var2'
Linux
0
```

The arbitrary `uname` command (thankfully harmless here) was run by `printf`.

For

```
printf "$var"
```

itself, there are fewer problems I can think of.

The most obvious one is the DoS one for things like `var=%1000000000s` which would spam the output with a lot of space characters or worse with things like `%.1000000000f` which would also use up a lot of memory and CPU time:

```
$ var=%.1000000000f command time -f 'max mem: %MK, elapsed: %E' bash -c 'printf "$var"' | wc -c
max mem: 4885344K, elapsed: 0:12.33
1000000002
```

Other DoS ones could be the `$var` values that trigger syntax errors because of incorrect format or incorrect options, causing `printf` to fail and the script it's invoked in along with it if the `errexit` option is enabled.

`printf "$var"` with `var='-va[1$(uname>&2)]'` doesn't seem to be a problem for `bash`, `ksh93` and `zsh`, the only three shells that I know that support that `-v varname` option, `zsh` treating it as the format, and the other two as a syntax error (because of the missing format)¹.

There's some minor information disclosure with ksh93 and bash with `export var='%(%Z %z)T\n'` that reveals the timezone of the script.

```
$ bash -c 'printf "$var"'
BST +0100
```

In `yash`, `printf "$var"` would call `printf` with more than one argument if `$var` was an array with more than one element, but `yash`'s `printf` doesn't do arithmetic evaluation and anyway its arithmetic evaluations are not affected by the same kind of [command injection vulnerabilities affecting ksh's, bash's or zsh's](/q/172103).

ksh93's `printf` is the one with the most extensions (all the date formatting, regexp format conversion, padding based on grapheme width, URI/HTML encoding...), and it still remains quite experimental. `printf "$data"` there exposes thousands of lines of code to that *data*. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a path for arbitrary command execution in there, possibly via some arithmetic expression evaluation or by triggering some bug in its own code². Of course, that could also happen with any `printf` implementation.

Problems with variable external data in the `printf()` C function,  are when they contain `%` sequences that end up dereferencing random memory areas on the stack. `printf(var)` when var is `%12$s` tries to print the byte values stored at the 12th argument passed to `printf`. Since `printf` is not passed any other argument, that will be something else that happens to be on the stack, and that could be pointer to some area of memory holding sensitive information. With `%n`, `printf()` would end up *writing* some number there.

```
$ tcc -run -w -xc - $'%6$s\n' <<<'f(char*f){char*s="secret";printf(f);}main(int c,char**v){f(v[1]);}'
secret
$ tcc -run -w -xc - $'%p%p%p%p%p\n%s\n' <<<'f(char*f){char*s="secret";printf(f);}main(int c,char**v){f(v[1]);}'
0x7fff1182db380x7fff1182db500x7900000x80x562b5ec0ba6a
secret
```

`printf` utilities may end up calling `printf()` or may implement all of it themselves (they have to at least to some extent as `%b` is not in `printf()`, and for numeric formats, they need to convert the arguments to numbers).

If they do call `printf()`, they will guard against calling it with not enough arguments to cover the format specification. That is a POSIX requirement that `printf "%s"` output nothing or that `printf %d` output 0 for instance, so `printf` implementations should pass enough empty string or 0 number arguments to `printf()`.

You could imagine poorly written `printf` implementations failing to do so properly. I'm not aware of any, but I've seen `awk` implementations in the past where their own `printf()` was affected (also via `OFMT` or `CONVFMT` there which involve `printf()` processing³).

---

<sup>¹ `print "$var"` is an arbitrary command injection vulnerability in `zsh` however via that vector. It's important to use `print -- $var` there, and even generally `print -r -- "$var"` is what you want there.</sup>

<sup>² As an example, I get a SEGV with `var='%(%.999999999999s)T'` with the ksh93 that comes with Ubuntu 20.04</sup>

<sup>³ Even today, with my current version of `busybox`, `busybox awk -v OFMT='%#x %#x %#x %#x %g' 'BEGIN {print 1.1}'` outputs `0x1 0x4 0x4 0x4624bb30 1.1` and `busybox awk -v OFMT='%n %g' 'BEGIN {print 1.1}'` segfaults.</sup>

Comment: @IsaaC, `--` is necessary with `print` in `zsh` to avoid the ACE, but not `printf`. `printf -vx` outputs `-vx` in `zsh` but gives an error in `bash`/`ksh`. In `zsh` (or any POSIX compliant printf), you'd still need `--` for `printf -- --` to output `--`. Other than that, yes, that's the problems I can think of. There may be others. I only singled out ksh93 because its `printf` implementation is orders of magnitude bigger than most others, but that doesn't mean that you can't have bugs in others as well.

Comment: Why is `time` quoted in your example for `var=%.1000000000f`?

Comment: @TooTea, to make sure the `time` keyword of the shell is not invoked, but the one from `/usr/bin` which on my system supports that `-f` option. The `time` keyword of my shell  (zsh) has equivalent features (with the `TIMEFMT` variable), but as it happens its `%M` is broken on systems other than darwin/macos as it gives the mem usage in MiB instead of KiB.

Comment: for the exemple : you use `var=%.1000000000f 'time' ...` : instead of `'time'` (which will bypass aliases and builtin named time), maybe use : `command time` instead? to ensure it bypasses also any function of the same name? `function ls { echo "foo"} ; \ls ; 'ls'; command ls` : the first 2 echo "foo", and the 3rd one really executes the first ls seen in $PATH

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks. I've added it in. Note that `command` (except in zsh) like `'time'` would not bypass a builtin (in a shell that has such a builtin) but both bypass the `time` keyword that Korn-like shells have which was the intent here.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're talking about the shell `printf` command  not the C `printf(3)` function, there possible vulnerabilities are more limited with proper quoting of `"$var"`.  The shell command won't allow for the traditional stack dumping that could be done in C.  But as
Stéphane's answer shows, there are some dangers even then, and command injection with unquoted expansion as in the example below.

*How* you use the output could also potentially cause impact on processing later on.

To create a dumb example:

```
tst()
{
    while [ "$x" == "" ]
    do
      read x
    done
    
    printf $x
}
```

The condition "$x is not empty" will pass, but the output of printf will be empty if the user entered `%s`.  So any routine assuming the output of `tst` is not empty could potentially fail.  That *could* lead to unexpected code paths being taken.

That *could* lead to a security issue, depending on the rest of the code.

Note there's a lot of "if" and "could" caveats's here. It's very dependent on the application.  That's why I said there's not an immediate impact.

So a standard defensive coding style would recommend specifying a format string if the input isn't trusted.  If the input is trusted then there's no need.

From a non-security perspective, you normally want output to match input; if the user entered `hello%sthere` you expect to see that, and not `hellothere`.

Comment: As Stéphane's answer points out, there's no immediate security vulnerability in `printf "$var"` from the question, but there is in your example without the double-quotes on the expansion.  But +1 anyway for pointing out a different kind of possible attack, via violating possible invariants in program logic instead of via code injection.

Comment: @PeterCordes there **are** immediate security vulnerabilities with both `printf "$var"` and `printf $var`, but it's a lot worse with the latter (is what I'm pointing out in my answer).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh right, security yes in terms of DoS, but not simple command injection is what I was thinking.