# How to use output of multiple commands in last execution command while chaining commands?

Tags: bash, text-processing, command-line, azure

I have two commands, as follows:

This one gives repo names:

```
az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv
```

output looks like:

```
name1
name2
...
```

This one gives digest codes for one repo:

```
az acr manifest list-metadata -r ${REGISTRY} --name ${REPO} --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv
```

output looks like:

```
digest1
digest2
...
```

I want to output both repo names and digest codes.

**Tried:**

```
az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv \ 
| xargs -I% az acr manifest list-metadata -r ${REGISTRY} --n % --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv \
| xargs -I% echo "%: %"
```

**Actual output:**

```
digest_code: digest_code
```

**Expected output:**

```
repo_name: digestcode
```

Comment: Please provide some example output of these `az` commands, and the corresponding final output you expect.

Comment: @muru I have added output to both commands. Can you please check and help?

Comment: When you say “`--n %`”, do you mean “`-` `-` `n` `⁠ ⁠` `%`”, or do you mean “``--n name1``” (and “``--n name2``”)?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I have updated my question. `--n %` is wrong, it is `--name ${REPO}` which will be `--name name1`. I am happy to see the new solution!

Comment: I ***guess**,* from reverse-engineering your attempted solution and the accepted answer, that you want *n₁ + n₂ + …* lines of output.  You show ***one*** line of expected output.  Please try to ask clearer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need something like:

```
export REPO
az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv |
  while IFS= read -r REPO; do
    az acr manifest list-metadata -r "$REGISTRY" --n "$REPO" --query '[?tags[0]==null].digest' -o tsv |
      awk '{print ENVIRON["REPO"]": "$0}'
  done
```

Calling `awk` to prefix the output of each manifest command with the corresponding repo name.

Or if you need to run other commands on each repo/digest pair:

```
az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv |
  while IFS= read -r repo; do
    az acr manifest list-metadata -r "$REGISTRY" --n "$repo" --query '[?tags[0]==null].digest' -o tsv |
      while IFS= read -r digest; do
        other-cmd --repo "$repo" --digest "$digest"
      done
  done
```

With `zsh`, you could also do:

```
for repo ( ${(f)"$(az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv)"} ) {
  digests=( ${(f)"$(az acr manifest list-metadata -r $REGISTRY --n $repo --query '[?tags[0]==null].digest' -o tsv)"})
  print -rC1 -- $repo': '$^digests
}
```

```
for repo ( ${(f)"$(az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv)"} )
  for digest ( ${(f)"$(az acr manifest list-metadata -r $REGISTRY --n $repo --query '[?tags[0]==null].digest' -o tsv)"})
    other-cmd --repo $repo --digest $digest
```

In a `Makefile`, that'd look like:

```
target:
    az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv | \
      while IFS= read -r repo; do \
        az acr manifest list-metadata -r "$$REGISTRY" --n "$$repo" --query '[?tags[0]==null].digest' -o tsv | \
          while IFS= read -r digest; do \
            other-cmd --repo "$$repo" --digest "$$digest"; \
          done; \
      done
```

While that's on several lines in the Makefile, those lines are joined together, trailing `\`s removed and the `$$`s changed to `$`s before passing the result to `sh -c`, hence the need to add a few `;`s  to separate commands in that inline shell script.

You may want to put the code in a script instead to make it cleaner.

Comment: I am trying to run inside makefile, Is there anything I need to change in syntax to access `$REPO` variable?

Comment: @Pythoncoder, in Makefile, shell code has to be on one line and `$`'s (all `$` even the one used in awk's code) must be escaped as `$$`. While that's perfectly doable, you'd be better of putting that code in a script and calling your script in the Makefile.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! If I need to run chain another `az` instead of `awk` which uses `repo, digest`, what changes need to make in this command?

Comment: Can you also explain why `export REPO` is needed?

Comment: See edit. `export REPO` is needed for the variable to passed in the environment of `awk` where it is retrieved with `ENVIRON["REPO"]`.

Comment: Thanks you so much, Stéphane. For some reason the command without environment variable works fast. I really appreciate your work and contribution to this community.

Answer (score 1):

I ***guess**,* from reverse-engineering your attempted solution
and the other answer,
that you want *n₁ + n₂ + …* lines of output, like

```
blue: sky
blue: berry
blue: jay
red: stop sign
red: cardinal
red: tomato
red: fire
green: grass
green: beans
```

[Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716703/80216#716709) is good,
especially if you have no idea
what characters might be in the repository names. 
However, it will not work on very old versions of Awk.

This very similar answer uses sed rather than Awk. 
sed is somewhat less resource-intensive and may run more quickly.

```
az acr repository list -n registry -o tsv |
  while IFS= read -r REPO; do
    az acr manifest list-metadata -r "$REGISTRY" --name "$REPO" \
                    --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv |
        sed "s/^/$REPO: /"
  done
```

(`export` not needed) 
This should behave the same as Stéphane’s answer
unless the repository names might contain `/` or `&`. 
The `/` is a commonly-used, but arbitrary, delimiter. 
If you are sure that the repository names don’t contain `&` or,
for example, `|`, then you can make it safer
by changing the `sed` command to

```
        sed "s|^|$REPO: |"
```

If the repository names might contain `&`,
that can be handled with a little more difficulty.

Note that the output will be potentially ambiguous / confusing
if any of the repository names or digest codes might contain `:` .

If none of the repository names or digest codes might contain space,
you can format the output as a nice table
by piping it into `column -t`.

---

By the way, see [`${variable_name}`
doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525).