# Understanding curly braces with numbers

Tags: shell-script

What is this code doing? Especially the `${1}.TmpOut`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -f mergedOrca.out ]; then
    echo "" > O2.out.orc
fi

cat ${1}.TmpOut >> O2.out.orc
```

Comment: This _isn't_ brace expansion (but you probably didn't know that). It's just a regular parameter expansion, just on the first positional parameter. `${1}` is the same as `$1`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Comment: This title isn’t really applicable, since you have no preconceived notions, but see [${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525), where this particular usage is addressed in a footnote. Please pay attention to the guidance that you should always quote your shell variable/parameter references (e.g., ``"${1}.TmpOut"`` or ``"${1}".TmpOut``) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing a [positional parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) in the last line. The value of the first argument to the script is `$1` or if you prefer, `${1}`.

The curly braces also resolve [ambiguity in expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell).