# Validate AIX Password for root from script

Tags: shell-script, password, aix

Looking for a way in a shell script to validate the password for for root on an (AIX) matches a standardized plain text password.  This query is similar to another one on this site.  I have access to root and can compile a c Program if needed.
I have been abel to find standard libraries to do this for HP-UX and Linux. Now I am working on AIX and I have been hitting nothing but road blocks.  I have been able to extract the salt and the hash and I know the plain text password.  I am wanting to input the salt and password and get back the password hash so the I can compare it to what is stored on the server.

Comment: Is there no libcrypt on AIX?

Comment: I did find /lib/libcrypt.a but I am not a c coder so I am not sure how to use it. I assume a header file might help but I have not found it.  I am fairly new to AIX.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with AIX, there may be a dedicated tool for that. This tool is likely to need to run as root, though.

Rather than code it yourself, I recommend using existing tools. Pass the password to `su` and test whether `su` succeeds. Note that you'll have to run `su` as root. Since `su` reads the password from the terminal, you'll need to use [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to pass it.

Here's a script inspired from [cluelessCoder's on a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459682/check-unix-username-and-password-in-a-shellscript/1503831#1503831). Note that this script needs to run as a non-root user, otherwise `su` will not prompt for a password.

```
#!/bin/sh
PASSWORD=swordfish

expect << EOF
spawn su -c exit
expect "Password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
set wait_result  [wait]

# check if it is an OS error or a return code from our command
#   index 2 should be -1 for OS erro, 0 for command return code
if {[lindex \$wait_result 2] == 0} {
        exit [lindex \$wait_result 3]
} 
else {
        exit 1 
}
EOF
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "The password is correct"
else
  echo "The password is wrong"
fi
```

If you have Perl, or if you want to use a C program, see [this answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/how-to-check-password-with-linux/21728#21728) which shows how to extract the password hash and compute a hash of the supplied password with the same salt, under Linux. You may need to adjust the hash extraction if your system uses the traditional DES scheme.

Comment: I can not use expect as this is not normaly available or installed on AIX servers. I have extracted the password hash and salt.  What I have not found on the AIX servers is the crypt library that would  allow me to use the salt and plain text password to caculate the hash.  AIX like a lot of older UNIX flavors still use crypt based on the normal DES hashing scheme.

Comment: @RLGJR `crypt(3)` is a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/crypt.html) function, so it should be available on AIX. Is there a `c89` command? Does it find `crypt()`?

Comment: @RLGJR [This C code snippet](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/passwd.html) may help.

Comment: I do have c89 on one server and the code snippet looks useful.  I will see if I can get it to do what I want.

Comment: Gilles thank you for your help. Your answers led me to what I was looking for. In some of the othe older *nix they use either crypt or bigcrypt and I was able to find libraries via the man pages. With AIX could not find it even when I attempted the find command. The C code snippet showed me where the libraries were stored. With that I was abel to write this small C program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>

   /* 1st param is the desired password  */
   /* 2nd param is 2 char salt           */

main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
char *p;
p=crypt(argv[1],argv[2]);
printf("%s",p);
}