# How to confirm linux root password from ssh root?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, password, authentication

How can I check a remote machines root password?

I have a remote machines that are normally accessed via ssh root and other users. For security purposes I have a script to change all keys and user passwords periodically from a central server.

For non root users the password is updated like so.

```
ssh -i a_priv_key root@ip "echo 'user:NEWPASS' | chpasswd"
```

And I check it has actually changed with this.

```
ssh -i b_priv_key user@ip "echo NEWPASS | sudo -S ls /root"
```

However if I want to do the same with the root user I am stuck. The sudo -S ls /root always returns a listing with any password because we just ssh'd in to the remote machine as root.

And if we ssh in as user sudo prompts for user's password.

I have been trying to get something with su user && su root because I noticed it will prompt for a root password but am not able to script it like the above.

'login root' from the root shell will also always prompt for a password but I cannot script the clear-text password to that either.

I have read this question but was hoping for a inbuilt method to do it rather than writing a custom application that must be installed on the remote machines. 
[How to check password with Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/how-to-check-password-with-linux)

Comment: Using `expect` is a good way to automate that for commands that read the password from a pty (like you mentioned `su` or `login`.) You can run `expect` locally and have it start the ssh connection, so no need to install it on the remote machines.

Comment: Also note that using `echo NEWPASS` on ssh is quite insecure! It might make it into log files and even be visible from `ps`, so you'd be leaking your passwords. At the very least, use something like `<<<NEWPASS` (assuming `bash`, this is a `bash` syntax) passing that to the stdin of ssh itself rather than as part of the command string. But `expect` is possibly a better way to make this slightly more secure (still pretty scary though.)

Comment: "_For security purposes I have a script to change all keys and user passwords periodically from a central server_" - why aren't you using that central server to authenticate users directly? Then no need for password files on any of the satellite systems, and no need for scripts to distribute administrative level passwords (or hashes)

Comment: Because you'd be unable to authenticate if for some reason connectivity to that one server for down? Even if you have have an HA cluster of LDAP machines, for instance, if the server you need to do maintenance on because it e.g. lost it's primary interface due to some glitch you'd be screwed and couldn't even log in via a console ... sure, you could still boot of a rescue CD, the question is then how much downtime can that one machine afford.

Answer (score 1):

If configuring `sudo` on the target machine is an option, then you can set up `rootpw` for some certain command, which makes `sudo` ask for the root password rather than the user password. For example, you could add the following line in a file 
`/etc/sudoers.d/lsrootpw` (and restart `sudo` service if needed)

```
Defaults!/bin/ls        rootpw
```

By that, any user except root, when doing `sudo ls` will be asked the root password rather than their own password. Thus, you could test with

```
ssh -i b_priv_key root@ip su user sudo -S ls /root <<< "NEWPASS"
```

which would go one way or the other depending on whether the password `NEWPASS` is correct for `root` or not. That test will require a sudo user on the target.

Or, if you have Debian's `runuser` command, you could rather use `nobody` as in the following:

```
ssh -i b_priv_key root@ip runuser -u nobody -- sudo -S ls /root <<< "NEWPASS"
```

That should also consistently yield two different results depending on the password's correctness. In particular, a correct password results in a complaint about `nobody` not being in the `sudoers` file. Though you could deal with that by an additional declaration in `/etc/sudoers.d/lsrootpw`.

Of course, all in all this is not much different from having a custom application as it requires the installation of something on the target host(s). At the same time, it's all doable with a sequence of five remote commands (add `lsrootpw`, restart `sudo`, make the test, remove `lsrootpw` and restart sudo again)